# UnicodeDecodeError in CSV readiring in Python

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file and when I try to read it in Python 2.7, it makes following error.

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)
```

This is my code so far,

```
with open('train.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
for row in reader:
    text=(row['Descript'])
    emotion = (row['Category'])
```

I found many solution from this site like [How to fix: "UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21129020/how-to-fix-unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte), [UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10561923/unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xef-in-position-1)
But they are not able to fix my error. Can anyone help me.

Comment: Why are you reading the file in binary mode?

Comment: If i used 'r' instead of 'rb', it also make the same error.

Comment: this  might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23917729/switching-to-python-3-causing-unicodedecodeerror and: python2 or python3? then one or two of your offending input-lines might be helpful for people wanting to help.

Comment: could have been easier if you wrote the csv with `str.encode('utf-8')`

Comment: Use Python 3, if possible. If not possible, use it anyways. Or [unicodecsv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/unicodecsv/0.14.1)

Comment: @ChathurikaJayawardana it would, the code is Python 2

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. Character 0x8b is ‹ (left angle quotation mark) in the Latin-1 encoding, but from what you report there is no way to tell what encoding your file is in. Edit your question to include the line of data where the program reports the error. If you don't know where that is, put a temporary `print` statement inside your loop to identify it.