# Loading UTF-8 file in Python 3 using numpy.genfromtxt()

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, utf-8

I am trying to read a file containing data for different dates using `numpy.genfromtxt()` in python3. The file basically looks like

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume
1-Apr-15,108.33,108.66,108.33,108.66,290
```

but may contain missing values marked as `-`.

The following code works fine in python2

```
str2date = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%d-%b-%y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
data = np.genfromtxt('test.dat', dtype="S9,f8,f8,f8,f8,f8", delimiter=',', names=True,  missing_values='-', converters={0: str2date})
```

but fails in python3 with

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

`locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` returns UTF-8 as the default encoding and the suggested solution by setting the encoding for the input stream suggested for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23917729/switching-to-python-3-causing-unicodedecodeerror) is a bit tricky. I also tried setting the [encoding of the terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10561923/unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xef-in-position-1) without success. I also have to admit, that I do not see a solution to my problem in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33001373/loading-utf-8-file-in-python-3-using-numpy-genfromtxt) as there are no special characters contained in the file -- or at least I do not see them.

How can I solve this issue without stepping back to python2?

Comment: It seems that genfromtxt falls in ascii mode for undefined reason.... have you tried genfromtxt(open('test.dat', encoding='utf-8'), ... ? or more efficient,
pandas.read_csv ?

Comment: `genfromtxt(open('test.dat', encoding='utf-8'))` complains about bytes provides instead of a string. But pandas works like a charm. Thanks :). It you put that in an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: `genfromtxt` opens the file in binary mode, and works with bytestrings (Py3).  The `converters` solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33001373/loading-utf-8-file-in-python-3-using-numpy-genfromtxt doesn't help?

Comment: I understood that as a workaround for a problematic file name. Which I do not have.

Answer (score 0):

When I try to reproduce your code I get problems with the date conversion:

```
Out[405]: b'1-Apr-15'
In [406]: str2date(_)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
----> 1 str2date = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%d-%b-%y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not bytes
```

If I add a `decode`:

```
def foo(x):
    return str2date(x.decode())
```

the converter handles the byte string that `genfromtxt` insists on providing.

```
In [410]: data = np.genfromtxt('stack47619155.txt', dtype="S9,f8,f8,f8,f8,f8", 
     ...: delimiter=',', names=True,  missing_values='-', converters={0: foo})
In [411]: data
Out[411]: 
array([(b'2015-04-0',  108.33,  108.66,  108.33,  108.66,  290.),
       (b'2015-04-0',     nan,  108.66,     nan,  108.66,  290.),
       (b'2015-04-0',  108.33,  108.66,  108.33,  108.66,   nan)],
      dtype=[('Date', 'S9'), ('Open', '<f8'), ('High', '<f8'), ('Low', '<f8'), ('Close', '<f8'), ('Volume', '<f8')])
In [412]: data = np.genfromtxt('stack47619155.txt', dtype="U9,f8,f8,f8,f8,f8", 
     ...: delimiter=',', names=True,  missing_values='-', converters={0: foo})
In [413]: data
Out[413]: 
array([('2015-04-0',  108.33,  108.66,  108.33,  108.66,  290.),
       ('2015-04-0',     nan,  108.66,     nan,  108.66,  290.),
       ('2015-04-0',  108.33,  108.66,  108.33,  108.66,   nan)],
      dtype=[('Date', '<U9'), ('Open', '<f8'), ('High', '<f8'), ('Low', '<f8'), ('Close', '<f8'), ('Volume', '<f8')])
```

It's a different error, so I may have used a different `-` as the missing field marker or not.

You found my post from a couple of years ago with a `decode` in the converters:

[Loading UTF-8 file in Python 3 using numpy.genfromtxt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33001373/loading-utf-8-file-in-python-3-using-numpy-genfromtxt)

Comment: The `decode()` is required in python2. For python3 it throws an error (on my system). The conversion itself without `decode()` runs fine there `print(str2date('1-Apr-15'))`.

Comment: How about `print(str2date(b'1-Apr-15'))`?

Comment: Then I need the `decode`, true. But `genfromtxt` still fails with the `ascii` problem.