# Python 3 SQLAlchemey UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have some code which I'm finally getting around to updating to Python 3.

It runs in Docker using ubuntu:20.04 as the base image.

I am using SQLAlchemy query .all() method `method sqlalchemy.orm.Query.all()`

The code works with Python 2 however, it fails on Python 3 with the following error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe7 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)

I am struggling to understand why the code is trying to decode to ascii.

I've set the locale in the Dockerfile and running `locale.getlocale()` on the line above the SQLAlchemy line prints `('en_US', 'UTF-8')`

The SQLAlchemy connection url specifies utf8:

`sqlalchemy.url='mysql+pymysql:{server}&charset=utf8&binary_prefix=true`

I've read all the other similar questions but still cannot get this working.

Update:

I've tracked it down to one column:

```
from sqlalchemy import PickleType


class Schedule(OrgRefMixin, DeclarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = 'flights'
    ...
        routing = Column(PickleType())
    ...
```

This is a blob column in the database.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/code/flights/flights/json.py", line 182, in view_wrapper
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/code/flights/flights/blueprints/flights.py", line 62, in get_flights
    flights = Flights.get(filters, **valid_args)
  File "/code/flights/flights/resources/flights.py", line 254, in get
    response = query.all()
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2643, in all
    return list(self)
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py", line 90, in instances
    util.raise_from_cause(err)
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 202, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 186, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py", line 77, in instances
    rows = [keyed_tuple([proc(row) for proc in process])
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py", line 77, in <listcomp>
    rows = [keyed_tuple([proc(row) for proc in process])
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py", line 77, in <listcomp>
    rows = [keyed_tuple([proc(row) for proc in process])
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/result.py", line 93, in __getitem__
    return processor(self._row[index])
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/sqltypes.py", line 1478, in process
    return loads(value)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe7 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: A complete stack trace might be helpful. Also, what versions of SQLAlchemy and PyMySQL are you using?

Comment: Thanks, I've added full stack trace. I'm using sqlalchemy==1.1.3 and pymysql==0.9.2

Comment: Wow, those versions are *really* old. Are you hitting a similarly old version of MySQL server?

Comment: I understand they're very old and I will be updating them. However, I'm not sure if it's related/causing this issue.

Comment: FWIW, I am unable to reproduce your issue using SQLAlchemy 1.1.3 and PyMySQL 0.9.2 hitting a MySQL 5.7.32 server. Can you create a [mcve] that uses just SQLAlchemy and PyMySQL (without Flask)?

Comment: A possibly related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60195845/2144390) mentions checking if `$LANG=C`

Comment: I'm still trying to get a minimal reproducible example, and while debugging I've tracked it down to one specific model class. Where a column which is `Collation: utf8_general_ci` `varchar(30)` in the database is down as a Unicode column type in the python class definition. I'm guessing this is related / incorrect?

Comment: No, that shouldn't be a problem. `sql.sqltypes.String` and `sql.sqltypes.Unicode` are used to specify column types for databases that differentiate between single-byte character sets (SBCSs) and Unicode. For example, MS SQL Server uses `varchar()` (`'literal example'`) and `nvarchar()` (`N'literal example'`) respectively. With other databases like MySQL and PostgreSQL we can use either `String` or `Unicode` because they both correspond to `varchar()`.

Comment: Thats a pity, was really hoping I was onto some there. If I run the raw sql command directly through sqlalchemy it works so it's something in the model classes that is causing the issue.

Comment: [This code](https://gist.github.com/gordthompson/e9da0be84d7d3d0ed4d302b60560d218) works for me on my Ubuntu 20.04 workstation using SQLAlchemy 1.1.3 and PyMySQL 0.9.2 hitting a MySQL 5.7.32 server. Does it fail for you>

Comment: That code works for me, so it's definitely something to do with the my python models/SQLAlchemy code. Strangely, if I change `_rrule = Column("rrule", PickleType())` to `_rrule = Column("rrule", Text())` the decode error does not occur.

Comment: You might be encountering an issue (hinted at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11305924/2144390)) where objects pickled by Python_2 are not 100% compatible with un-pickling in Python_3. You could try retrieving the raw bytes with something like `bin_data = engine.execute("SELECT routing FROM flights WHERE id = 1").scalar()` and then see if you can un-pickle it manually with `thing = pickle.loads(bin_data)`.

Comment: @GordThompson I'd say you're right. I'll try some digging around tomorrow and see if I can come up with a custom type so I can still use the ORM functionality of sqlalchemy. Appreciate all the help

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28218466/2144390

Answer (score 0):

when Python tries to decode a byte string to Unicode using the ASCII codec, but the byte the input string contains non-ASCII characters such a error happens. it seems that one of the rows being loaded contains non-ASCII characters. My suspect is explicitly set the encoding used by PickleType to 'bytes'. something like this:

```
routing = Column(PickleType(pickler=lambda v: pickle.dumps(v, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL), 
                                    unpickler=lambda v: pickle.loads(v), 
                                    encoding='bytes'))
```