# 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xae' in position 51: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, mysql, encoding

I'm going to insert data to a table in mysql:

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO master_product(category_Id, manufacture_Id, asin, title,image, description) \
                VALUES (%s,%s,%s, %s,%s, %s)',(category_Id, manufacture_Id, asin, title, image, description))
```

but I'm getting: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xae' in position 51: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Looks like one of your inputs is UTF-8 and something somewhere (you didn't paste a stacktrace) is expecting ascii only, and implicit conversion isn't doing the job.

Answer (score 1):

One of your parameters is a Unicode string and being implicitly encoded to a byte string using the default `ascii` codec.  Print the type of your parameters to help figure it out:

```
print type(category_Id)
print type(manufacture_Id)
etc...
```

Comment: I'm using Amazon product ApI data. to escape quote and double quote  I call the execute method with the text as a second *parametar*.  after that I got: "'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xae' in position 51: ordinal not in range(128)"

Comment: Yes, and one or more (or all) of those parameters are Unicode strings.  Because you are mixing byte strings and Unicode strings, Python is implicitly encoding the Unicode strings using the `ascii` codec.  Either use all Unicode strings (if mysql supports it) or use all byte strings.  Note that your insert command is a byte string.  It may be as simple as making that a Unicode string if all your parameters are Unicode, but I don't know if mysql supports that.  I don't use it.

Comment: do you mean using this method: .decode('utf-8') I changed my code to : title.decode('utf-8') but it return nothing I mean now title = '' "

Answer (score 0):

- The u'\xae in Unicode means ® (Registered Trademark)
- One of your parameter may be a unicode string containing u'\xae and you must be using Python 2.x
- You shall try to upgrade your Python to 3.x to prevent this error.

This link may provide more info ---> [How to fix: "UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21129020/how-to-fix-unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte)