# Python - Change string to utf8

Tags: python, utf-8, ascii, utf8-decode

I am trying to write Portuguese to an HTML file but I am getting some funny characters.  How do I fix this?

```
first = """<p style="color: red; font-family: 'Liberation Sans',sans-serif">{}</p>""".format(sentences1[i]) 
f.write(first)
```

Expected Output:
Hoje, nós nos unimos ao povo...

Actual Output in browser (Firefox on Ubuntu):
ï»¿Hoje, nÃ³s nos unimos ao povo...

I tried doing this:

```
first = """<p style="color: red; font-family: 'Liberation Sans',sans-serif">{}</p>""".format(sentences1[i]) 
f.write(first.encode('utf8'))
```

Output in terminal:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 65: ordinal not in range(128)

Why am I getting this error and also how can I write other languages to an HTML doc without the funny characters?
Or, is there a different file type that I can write to with the above font formatting?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21129020/how-to-fix-unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte

Answer (score 1):

Your format string should be a Unicode string too:

```
first = u"""<p style="color: red; font-family: 'Liberation Sans',sans-serif">{}</p>""".format(sentences1[i]) 
f.write(first)
```

Comment: I am still getting this error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Where does your `sentences1` list comes from? Can you post the code for it too?

Comment: @kedar Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "p.py", line 80, in <module>
    first = u"""<p style="color: red; font-family: 'Liberation Sans',sans-serif">{}</p>""".format(sentences1[i]) 
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: @ selcuk the sentences1 list is derived from a file.  Each sentence is read and stored in the list.  My code works perfectly on English text.  If I try to write to a different language, I get funny symbols.  So I tried to changed the codec and then I get the errors.

Comment: Do you decode according to the encoding of the file when reading from it?

Comment: Also, when I print to the terminal, all the Portuguese letters come out fine

Comment: @kedar - I don't decode anything.  This is the code for the source file: f = open('source1.txt', 'r') - 
text1 = f.read()

Answer (score 0):

[The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

^ Read it!

This is what happens when you try to use `.format` on text read from a file with *special* characters.

```
>>> mystrf = u'special text here >> {} << special text'
>>> g = open('u.txt','r')
>>> lines = g.readlines()
>>> mystrf.format(lines[0])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
>>>
```

Python tries to decode the text from the file as ASCII. So how do we fix that.

We simply tell python the proper encoding.

```
>>> line = mystrf.format(lines[0].decode('utf-8'))
>>> print line
special text here >> ß << special text
```

But when we try to write to a file again. It doesn't work.

```
>>> towrite.write(line)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xdf' in position 21: ordinal not in range(128)
```

We encode the line before writing to a file again.

```
>>> towrite.write(line.encode('utf-8'))
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're working with a string that is already UTF-8 encoded, so that's OK. The problem is that the meta tag in the HTML output is identifying the text as something other than `UTF-8`. For example, you may have `<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">`; you need to change it to `<meta charset="UTF-8">`.

The term for this kind of character set confusion is [Mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake).

P.S. Your string starts with a [Byte Order Mark (BOM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), you might want to remove it before working with the string.