# Pip install django-toolbelt get an error :" codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0] UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2

Tags: python, pip

I use Arch linux with Python 3 default. I use Konsole to download django-toolbelt with command `pip install django-toolbelt`. 
Name: pip
Version: 6.1.1

I get an error

```
Collecting django-toolbelt
  Using cached django-toolbelt-0.0.1.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): django in ./venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from django-toolbelt)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): psycopg2 in ./venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from django-toolbelt)
Collecting gunicorn (from django-toolbelt)
  Using cached gunicorn-19.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting dj-database-url (from django-toolbelt)
  Using cached dj_database_url-0.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting dj-static (from django-toolbelt)
  Using cached dj-static-0.0.6.tar.gz
Collecting static3 (from dj-static->django-toolbelt)
  Using cached static3-0.6.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-w5v7urb2/static3/setup.py", line 52, in <module>
        long_description=open('README.rst').read(),
      File "/home/phi/python/venv/lib/python3.4/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
        return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 2097: ordinal not in range(128)

    ----------------------------------------
    Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-w5v7urb2/static3
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Post full traceback. Also post exact version of pip.

Comment: look heer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21129020/how-to-fix-unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte

Comment: @Alik check it again for me. thank you and @ Ebre i tried but not working

Comment: @user3863069 what locale do you use?

Comment: @user3863069 provide output of `locale`.

Comment: @Alik
 C
POSIX
en_US
en_US.iso88591
en_US.utf8

it it exactly locale?

Comment: LANG=C
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_PAPER="C"
LC_NAME="C"
LC_ADDRESS="C"
LC_TELEPHONE="C"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C"
LC_ALL=

Comment: @user3863069 OK, try to execute this `LC_ALL=en_US.utf8 pip install django-toolbelt`

Comment: OH MY GOD, many thanks to you,  i did it, i can tell you how im happy. You save me one week. Thank you very much!

Comment: @user3863069 I'll post it as an aswer along with an explanation then

Comment: @user3863069 if the answer below solved your question then [accept it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251399/471899) please

Answer (score 3):

Run

```
LC_ALL=en_US.utf8 pip install django-toolbelt
```

---

There is a problem in `pip`. If you use non-unicode locales like `C` and try to install a package with `pip` `UnicodeDecodeErrors` may be thrown when `setup.py` tries to read files containing non-ASCII characters.

In this case it were acute accents ´ introduced in [this change](https://github.com/rmohr/static3/commit/d442c93f987b55c61af62af4478cebdcce777de8#diff-88b99bb28683bd5b7e3a204826ead112).

I am going to report this issue on Github.