# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 20: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv

I have instaled virtualenv on windows 10 and Python 2.7.1 but when I run:

`virtualenv my-virtual`

I have this error:
`UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 20: ordinal not in range(128)`

I think Python 2.7 does not understand my windows path because accent mark...

[image]

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Have you tried adding `# encoding: utf-8` at the start of your script?

Comment: I have wirtten in virtualenv file `reload(sys)  
sys.setdefaultencoding('Cp1252')` and working for me. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21129020/how-to-fix-unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy solution is: change your name ;)   Of course I am joking, you shouldn't have to change your name because some tool is broken!

I can reproduce your problems with `virtualenv` :

```bash
/tmp$ mkdir "Carlos Andrés Moreno"
/tmp$ cd Carlos\ Andrés\ Moreno/
/tmp/Carlos Andrés Moreno$ virtualenv kernel
New python executable in kernel/bin/python2
Also creating executable in kernel/bin/python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 16: ordinal not in range(128)
ERROR: The executable kernel/bin/python2 is not functioning
ERROR: It thinks sys.prefix is u'/tmp/Carlos Andr\xe9s Moreno' (should be u'/tmp/Carlos Andr\xe9s Moreno/kernel')
ERROR: virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable
```

With using [virtualenvwrapper](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), I don't have any problem:

```bash
/tmp/Carlos Andrés Moreno$ mkvirtualenv kernel
New python executable in kernel/bin/python2
Also creating executable in kernel/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/wglenn/.virtualenvs/kernel/bin/predeactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/wglenn/.virtualenvs/kernel/bin/postdeactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/wglenn/.virtualenvs/kernel/bin/preactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/wglenn/.virtualenvs/kernel/bin/postactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/wglenn/.virtualenvs/kernel/bin/get_env_details
(kernel)/tmp/Carlos Andrés Moreno$
```

It seems they were more careful with handling non-ascii characters.  So try using the `mkvirtualenv` helper function from virtualenvwrapper.sh

Comment: "The easy solution is: change your name" -- You said that as a joke, but it actually is the _best_ solution: Change your account name. An account name that contains spaces, non-ascii characters or even upper case characters can cause needless problems. I speak from experience, as I have a given name containing an “é”.

Comment: I have mixed feelings on the issue.  For sure, practicality beats purity.  But on the other hand, if everybody takes this "lazy" approach then broken tools will never be fixed!  sadface.jpg