# Python 3: Solution for "'ascii' codec can't decode byte" while reading from a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

After running this simple program:

```
import os
#listo=[]
fin=open(os.path.expanduser("~/Downloads/Untitled.txt"))
for line in fin:
    print(line)
```

I get the error `'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 59: ordinal not in range(128)`. A similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21129020/how-to-fix-unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte) has solutions that seem to not work on Python 3.

I read that Python 3 uses utf-8 for encoding a txt file, then why is ascii used here? How can I solve this?

Thanks :)

Comment: Python uses your *system default* based on your locale. Don't depend on the locale, set `encoding` explicitly.

Comment: Explicit better than implicit - The Zen of Python.