# Using unicode / umlauts in Python: Dictionary v manual input

Tags: python, dictionary, unicode, replace, character-encoding

I am using a dictionary to store some character pairs in Python (I am replacing umlaut characters). Here is what it looks like:

```
umlautdict={
    'ae': 'ä',
    'ue': 'ü',
    'oe': 'ö'
    }
```

Then I run my inputwords through it like so:

```
for item in umlautdict.keys():
        outputword=inputword.replace(item,umlautdict[item])
```

But this does not do anything (no replacement happens). When I printed out my umlautdict, I saw that it looks like this:

```
{'ue': '\xfc', 'oe': '\xf6', 'ae': '\xc3\xa4'}
```

Of course that is not what I want; however, trying things like `unicode()` (--> Error) or pre-fixing `u` did not improve things.

If I type the *'ä'* or *'ö'* into the `replace()` command by hand, everything works just fine. I also changed the settings in my script (working in TextWrangler) to  `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` as it would net even let me execute the script containing umlauts without it.

So I don't get...

- Why does this happen? Why and when do the umlauts change from "good
  to evil" when I store them in the dictionary?
- How do I fix it?
- Also, if anyone knows: what is a good resource to learn about
  encoding in Python? I have issues all the time and so many things
  don't make sense to me / I can't wrap my head around.

I'm working on a Mac in Python 2.7.10. Thanks for your help!

Comment: What's your python version?

Comment: @Kasramvd Python 2.7.10 . I'll add it above

Comment: Pretty sure it **does** work and you're just messing it up with that non-logical use of `inputword` and `outputword`.

Comment: Take a look at `str.translate` method. It's more proper for such tasks.

Comment: For a brief overview of Unicode in Python 2.x see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21129020/how-to-fix-unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte/35444608#35444608

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Declare your coding.
2. Use **raw** format for the special characters.
3. Iterate properly on your string: keep the changes from each loop iteration as you head to the next.

Here's code to get the job done:

```
\# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

umlautdict = {
    'ae': r'ä',
    'ue': r'ü',
    'oe': r'ö'
    }

print umlautdict

inputword = "haer ueber loess"
for item in umlautdict.keys():
        inputword = inputword.replace(item, umlautdict[item])

print inputword
```

Output:

```
{'ue': '\xc3\xbc', 'oe': '\xc3\xb6', 'ae': '\xc3\xa4'}
här über löss
```

Answer (score 3):

Converting to Unicode is done by *decoding* your string (assuming you're getting bytes):

```
data = "haer ueber loess"
word = data.decode('utf-8')  # actual encoding depends on your data
```

Define your dict with unicode strings as well:

```
umlautdict={
    u'ae': u'ä',
    u'ue': u'ü',
    u'oe': u'ö'
    }
```

and finally `print umlautdict` will print out some representation of that dict, usually involving escapes. That's normal, you don't have to worry about that.