# Unicode decode error when trying to install Django

Tags: python, django, unicode

I am trying to install Django 1.6.11 but getting this error message:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xcf in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Full traceback:

```
(lwc_env) C:\Users\lenovo\PycharmProjects\lwc_env>pip install django==1.6.11
Collecting django==1.6.11
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\PycharmProjects\lwc_env\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 223, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\PycharmProjects\lwc_env\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 293, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\PycharmProjects\lwc_env\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 705, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\PycharmProjects\lwc_env\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 334, in prepare_files
    functools.partial(self._prepare_file, finder))
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\PycharmProjects\lwc_env\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 321, in _walk_req_to_install
    more_reqs = handler(req_to_install)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\PycharmProjects\lwc_env\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 461, in _prepare_file
    req_to_install.populate_link(finder, self.upgrade)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\PycharmProjects\lwc_env\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 249, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\PycharmProjects\lwc_env\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 486, in find_requirement
    all_versions = self._find_all_versions(req.name)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\PycharmProjects\lwc_env\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 404, in _find_all_versions
    index_locations = self._get_index_urls_locations(project_name)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\PycharmProjects\lwc_env\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 378, in _get_index_urls_locations
    page = self._get_page(main_index_url)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\PycharmProjects\lwc_env\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 818, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\PycharmProjects\lwc_env\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 928, in get_page
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=600",
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\PycharmProjects\lwc_env\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 477, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\PycharmProjects\lwc_env\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 373, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\PycharmProjects\lwc_env\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 465, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\PycharmProjects\lwc_env\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 605, in send
    r.content
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\PycharmProjects\lwc_env\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\models.py", line 750, in content
    self._content = bytes().join(self.iter_content(CONTENT_CHUNK_SIZE)) or bytes()
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\PycharmProjects\lwc_env\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\models.py", line 673, in generate
    for chunk in self.raw.stream(chunk_size, decode_content=True):
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\PycharmProjects\lwc_env\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\response.py", line 307, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\PycharmProjects\lwc_env\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\response.py", line 243, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\PycharmProjects\lwc_env\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\filewrapper.py", line 54, in read
    self.__callback(self.__buf.getvalue())
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\PycharmProjects\lwc_env\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\controller.py", line 244, in cache_response
    self.serializer.dumps(request, response, body=body),
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\PycharmProjects\lwc_env\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 276, in set
    return super(SafeFileCache, self).set(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\PycharmProjects\lwc_env\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\caches\file_cache.py", line 99, in set
    with self.lock_class(name) as lock:
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\PycharmProjects\lwc_env\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\lockfile\mkdirlockfile.py", line 18, in __init__
    LockBase.__init__(self, path, threaded, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\PycharmProjects\lwc_env\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\lockfile\__init__.py", line 189, in __init__
    hash(self.path)))
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\PycharmProjects\lwc_env\lib\ntpath.py", line 85, in join
    result_path = result_path + p_path
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xcf in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I am using PyCharm on Windows 7 if this matters. Is there a problem with my computer or am I just doing something wrong?

Thank you for help!

Comment: Because I am a beginner and following a tutorial. The tutorial is for 1.6. But the version doesn't really matter because I've tried to install the latest version and still get this error. :(

Comment: Try this Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21129020/how-to-fix-unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte

Comment: Django 1.6? Windows 7? You really like old versions...

Comment: And? Does this mean they are not supposed to work or what? The latest version of Django gives the same mistake.

Comment: Django version is irrelevant. This is a problem with `pip`, and would happen for any library. @hickstead are you using a machine with a non-ASCII character in the host name? That would seem to be a problem with a pip dependency, see [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/pylockfile/+bug/1463965).