# Error when installing scikits.audiolab on Raspberry PI 1

Tags: raspberry-pi, scikits

When trying to install scikts.audiolab with pip install scikits.audiolab on my raspberry PI 1 I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.5.6', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 248, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 161, in main
    text = '\n'.join(complete_log)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 55: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How can I fix this? I unfortunately don't have much experience with Linux :(

Comment: Maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21129020/how-to-fix-unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte

Comment: Thank you. I've read that thread, but I couldn't find what to do to fix the error?

Comment: Can you type: head /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py and tell me what the first line says?

Comment: This fixed it:
sudo pip install -U pip
sudo pip install scikits.audiolab