# Getting numbers from html tags

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, urllib

I'm trying to get the **numbers** in the "span" tag from this link: http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.html

The data looks like this:

```
<tr><td>Modu</td><td><span class="comments">90</span></td></tr>
<tr><td>Kenzie</td><td><span class="comments">88</span></td></tr>
<tr><td>Hubert</td><td><span class="comments">87</span></td></tr>
```

Here's the code:

```
import urllib
from BeautifulSoup import *

url = raw_input('Enter - ')
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

# Retrieve all of the anchor tags
tags = soup('span')


numbers = [number.contents[0] for number in tags]
print numbers
```

When I print `numbers`, it displays something like this:

```
[u'97', u'97', u'90', u'90', u'88', u'87', u'87', u'80', u'79', u'79', u'78', u'76', u'76', u'72', u'72', u'66', u'66', u'65', u'65', u'64', u'61', u'61', u'59', u'58', u'57', u'57', u'54', u'51', u'49', u'47', u'40', u'38', u'37', u'36', u'36', u'32', u'25', u'24', u'22', u'21', u'19', u'18', u'18', u'14', u'12', u'12', u'9', u'7', u'3', u'2']
```

Why is it getting those u's? my objective is to cast those strings without the u's and get the sum of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list items are of unicode type, you can convert your list items to strings like below:

```
numbers = [str(number.contents[0]) for number in tags]
```

To sum up your list items, you will need to convert them to integers, not strings:

```
numbers = [int(number.contents[0]) for number in tags]
s = sum(numbers)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> my_list = [u'97', u'97', u'90', u'90', ...]
>>>
>>> [str(item) for item in my_list]
['97', '97', '90', '90', ...]
>>> 
>>> s = sum(int(item) for item in my_list)
>>> s
2553
```

Comment: You should never encode a Unicode (`str()`) without passing an encoding type. If any of the fields contain non-ASCII, then the user will get a massive UnicodeEncodeError exception

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack I agree with you, just in this case I see that inputs are numbers not non ascii characters.

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing that because you're printing the list. This invokes Python `repr()` method to give you an idea of the data types in the list.

`u''` means your list contains Unicode strings. You don't need to worry about this right now (See [How to fix: "UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21129020/how-to-fix-unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte/35444608#35444608) for more details).

As you need to sum your values, you just need to convert your Unicode string values to integers.

You can achieve that by slightly modifying your code with:

```
numbers = [int(number.contents[0]) for number in tags]
```