# python: replacing a regular character with an unicode one using regex re.sub

Tags: python, regex, unicode, character-encoding

I have a simple problem that is driving me crazy, and seems to be due to the handling in python of `unicode` characters.

I have `latex` table stored on my disk (very similar to http://www.jwe.cc/downloads/table.tex), and I want to apply some regex on it so that hyphens `-` (`\u2212`) are replaced by en-dashes `–` (`alt 0150` or `\u2013`)

I am using the following function that performs two different regex-and-replace.

```
import re
import glob

def mychanger(fileName):
  with open(fileName,'r') as file:
    str = file.read()
    str = str.decode("utf-8")
    str = re.sub(r"((?:^|[^{])\d+)\u2212(\d+[^}])","\\1\u2013\\2", str).encode("utf-8")
    str = re.sub(r"(^|[^0-9])\u2212(\d+)","\\1\u2013\\2", str).encode("utf-8")
  with open(fileName,'wb') as file:
    file.write(str)

myfile = glob.glob("C://*.tex")
for file in myfile: mychanger(file)
```

Unfortunately, this does not change anything.

It works though, if I use a non unicode character like `$` instead of `\u2013`, which means the regex code is correct.

I am lost here, I tried using `re.sub(ur"((?:^|[^{])\d+)\u2212(\d+[^}])","\\1\u2013\\2", str).encode("utf-8")` but it still does not change anything.

What is wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: Try: `u"\\1\u2013\\2"`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ thanks let me try asap

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I get `TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found`

Comment: Noobie, why are you passing a list? It seems the code you post here isn't the code you're running.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ please see update. may come from `glob`

Comment: @Qeek still getting this `TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found`.

Comment: Try to encode the string only when all substitutions are done.

Comment: @Qeek, thanks! but I tried that, namely  `str = str.decode("utf-8")
    str = re.sub(r"((?:^|[^{])\d+)" + "\u2212" + r"(\d+[^}])",u"\\1\u2013\\2", str).encode("utf-8")`

Comment: @Qeek still no changes. Can you possibly try using the latex table available on the link I posted? That stuff is driving me nuts!!!!! :( thanks again for helping

Comment: _DashPunctuation_ hyphen-minus is  `-` (`\u002D`) differs from  _MathSymbol_ Minus Sign `−` (`\u2212`) .

Comment: @JosefZ woooooooooooooot ! let me try asap!!!

Comment: @JosefZ still no change. does that work for you? if yes, can you please post a solution?

Comment: Python 2.x or 3.x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example file actually contains `HYPHEN-MINUS` (U+002D) not U+2212.

If even if it did contain the right characters, you're hitting all the n00b issues of Python 2.x Unicode:

1. Decoding and encoding inline. In fact you encode twice!
2. Use of Unicode literal (`\u2212`) not in a Unicode string
3. Unnecessary use of `r` raw modifier

My advice is to remove all decodes and encodes and allow Python to do it for you. The `io` module backports the Python 3.x behaviour and decodes files for you. I've also renamed `str` to `my_str` to avoid conflicts with Python's own `str` class.

```
import re
import glob
import io

def mychanger(fileName):
    with io.open(fileName,'r', encoding="utf-8") as file:
        my_str = file.read()

        my_str = re.sub(u"((?:^|[^{])\d+)\u002d(\d+[^}])", u"\\1\u2013\\2", my_str)
        my_str = re.sub(u"(^|[^0-9])\u002d(\d+)",          u"\\1\u2013\\2", my_str)

    with io.open(fileName, 'w', encoding="utf-8") as file:
        file.write(my_str)

myfile = glob.glob(C://*.tex")

for file in myfile: mychanger(file)
```

For a thorough explanation of Python 2.x and Unicode, see [How to fix: "UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21129020/how-to-fix-unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte/35444608#35444608)

Comment: Thanks! Kind of make sense I hit the noobie issues dont you think :D

Comment: It's kinda unavoidable in Python 2 when you're copy-pasting code :) Oh and when the name fits ;)