# python, flask and mysql

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I would like help in just one thing

```
@app.route('/getdata', methods =['GET', 'POST'])
#@requires_auth
def get_data():

    config = {
        'user': 'user',
        'password': 'password.',
        'host': '127.0.0.1',
        'database': 'database',
        'raise_on_warnings': True,
        'use_pure': False,
    }

    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(**config)

    cur = cnx.cursor()

    cur.execute("SELECT hash FROM hash_files")


     rows = cur.fetchall()
     response = [row[0] for row in rows]

    return jsonify(response)


    cnx.close()
```

I get this error "tuple indices must be integers, not str" can someone help me please?

I got that error before, but now I have this one

```
      Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1997, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Python27\webapi\venv\webapi.py", line 59, in get_data
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\__init__.py", line 179, in connect
    return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 98, in __init__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 252, in close
    self.cmd_quit()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 581, in cmd_quit
    self._socket.send(packet, 0, 0)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\network.py", line 143, in send_plain
    errno=2055, values=(self.get_address(), _strioerror(err)))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\errors.py", line 185, in __init__
    self.msg = self.msg % values
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 46: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Sorry for the long error, I didin't knew if you need it all so I send like this

I had de program working with sqlite3 but I needed to use mysql so to get all the data on the web api and the other program getting the data to an array and it's not working now

Comment: Please edit your post to include the error printout

Comment: @0TTT0 I add it now, thanks

Comment: @ShwSvn you're trying to call the api using a different script and you're posting the trace back of that script. Please post the trace back from your original program.

Comment: The traceback you've posted says that you're trying to json decode the response you're getting from the API. When your API isn't returning you a json object at all.

Comment: @anupsabraham you are rigth, I'm sorry, I updated it

Comment: The error seems to happen during the `mysql.connector.connect()` call. Do you perhaps have any unicode characters in the hostname? This seems to be an encoding error that happens while processing a failed connection attempt.

Comment: @mata I don't think that I have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.fetchall()` function returns a list of tuple. So `row` is a tuple and you can't do `row['hash']`. That is why you're getting the error `tuple indices must be integers, not str`.

To access the values in the tuple, you need to use index: `row[0]`

**Edit:**

For fixing the decode error, you need to [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35444608/1666143). Since it is a long answer to post here and someone else has answered it very well, I'm not typing it all here.

Comment: Like that? I changed the post
But know I'm getting the other error that I posted

UnicodeDecodeError
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 46: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: @ShwSvn Please read this to have a better understanding of your current problem. https://stackoverflow.com/a/35444608/1666143

Comment: No, the stack trace shows that the error doesn't happen when getting the results but during `connect()`

Comment: I don't know, I restarted the pycharm and it was fixed with this change of row[0]
Thanks a lot to everyone