# Python: How to pass a unicode variable to sql server in cursor.execute()

Tags: python, unicode

On running python 2.7 script with code

```
with open(excelfile,'r') as openexcel:
    for line in openexcel:
        emp_firstname=line.split(',')[3]
        emp_lastname=line.split(',')[2]
        cursor.execute('SELECT id,Firstname,LastName FROM employee where 
        FirstName=? and LastName=?',emp_firstname,emp_lastname)
```

Here after `emp_firstname=line.split(',')[3]`, emp_firstname value is Narélen which throws an error as,

```
cursor.execute('SELECT id,Firstname,LastName FROM employee where FirstName=? and LastName=?',emp_firstname,emp_lastname)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I tried some google search too but still far away from expected result. Please suggest some way to get out of this error.

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21129020/how-to-fix-unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte

Comment: On adding,                                                                                         
import sys  
reload(sys)  
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
It threw no error but ended up without doing anything.

Comment: Please post the __full__ traceback, and the type of `emp_firstname` and `emp_lastname` (adds a `print(type(emp_firstname)); print(type(emp_lastname))` in your code and check your terminal).

Comment: I have got my answer by trying 
cursor.execute('SELECT id,Firstname,LastName FROM employee where FirstName=? and LastName=?',emp_firstname.decode('cp1252'),emp_lastname.decode('cp1252'))
Thanks all for your help!!