# Python decode unknown character

Tags: python, django, utf-8, decode

I'm trying to decode the following:
`UKLTD� For` into utf-8 (or anything really) but I cannot workout how to do it and keep getting errors like

> 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xae in position 8: ordinal not in
>   range(128)

I'm reading from a csv and have the following:

```
with open(path_to_file, 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        order = Order(
           ...
           product_name = row[11].encode('utf-8'),
           ...
        )
        order.save()
```

I would be happy right now to just ignore the character if I have keep the rest of the string.

Comment: `0xae` is also not a valid UTF-8 byte. It might be another character set (ISO-8859-1 perhaps?) Do you know the character is is supposed to be? In ISO-8859-1 it is ⓡ (registered sign).

Comment: use try except and in except use `product_name = row[11].encode('utf-16')`

Comment: maybe it can help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21129020/how-to-fix-unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21129020/how-to-fix-unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte

Comment: this sorted it: `product_name = row[11].decode('iso-8859-1').encode('utf8')`

Comment: @HenryM you could answer your own question. This way, other people might be helped as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to @BartFriederichs.

Solution is : `product_name = row[11].decode('iso-8859-1').encode('utf8')`