# 'ascii' codec can't encode... while uploading csv file

Tags: python, django, csv, unicode

I've got class for uploading my csv files with holidays to my fullcalendar. It looks like this:

```
class UploadVacationsView(APIView):
    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            # check file type
            mime = MimeTypes()
            url = urllib.pathname2url(request.FILES['file']._name)
            mime_type = mime.guess_type(url)
            if 'text/csv' not in mime_type:
                raise APIException(code=400, detail='File type must be CSV')
            vacations_list =[]
            csv_file = StringIO(request.data.get('file', None).read().decode('utf-8'))
            user_tz = pytz.timezone(request.user.common_settings.time_zone)
            schedule_file = ScheduleFile.objects.create(user=request.user)
            instance_hebcal = HebcalService()
            events = instance_hebcal.process_csv(csv_file, user_tz)
        ...
```

And in the other class, I've got a method that works with csv files:

```
class HebcalService(...):
    def process_csv(self, csv_file, user_tz):
        events = []
        csv_input = csv.reader(csv_file.readlines(), dialect=csv.excel)
        curr_row = 1
        start_date = None
        end_date = None
        start_name = None
        holiday_name = ''
        last_event = {'subject': '',
                     'date': '',
                     }

        for row in list(csv_input)[1:]:
            subject, date, time, _, _, _, _ = row[:7]
            curr_row += 1
            row = [unicode(cell.strip(), 'utf-8') for cell in row]

            if 'lighting' in subject and not start_date:
                start_date = user_tz.localize(format_datetime(date, time))
                if date == last_event['date']:
                    start_name = last_event['subject']
```

Everything is ok when working with english holiday's names but when I encounter hebrew names it shots an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/stas/work/vacation/vmode/apps/marketplaces/base/api/views.py", line 47, in put
    events = instance_hebcal.process_csv(csv_file, user_tz)
  File "/home/stas/work/vacation/vmode/apps/marketplaces/base/services/hebcal.py", line 106, in process_csv
    for row in list(csv_input)[1:]:
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 19-23: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I've read about making all strings to unicode but don't understand where it gets that default ASCII encoding, how can I handle it and save string with `holiday_name` from csv file?

Comment: Can you check the encoding of your csv file?

Comment: Chek this answer, it may be what you need https://stackoverflow.com/a/47945317/6005145

Comment: Are you still using Python 2.x? Because the `csv` module supports Unicode out of the box in Python 3, but it's a pain to use it with non-English text in Python 2.

Comment: @guillermo chamorro, I checked using unicodeDammit it gave me: [windows-1252], [iso-8859-1], [iso-8859-2]. I thought about using BitesI0, but all my sorting is based on strings match

Comment: @lenz, yes work project is in Python 2.7 and I can do nothing with it

Comment: You mean you can do nothing about the Python version? Well, than I suggest (1) you use [unicodecsv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/unicodecsv) (`pip install unicodecsv`), and (2) you make your code Unicode-aware, ie. use Unicode strings (`u"..."`) everywhere, otherwise you'll continue to have implicit coercion with potential encoding errors. To ease the pain with the `u"..."` strings, consider using `from __future__ import unicode_literals`.