# python 3.x have an error while reading a file. 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 3582: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python

When reading a file with this code faced error:

```
with open("hist", "rb") as f:
    hist = pickle.load(f)


hist = pickle.load(f)
```

Error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 3582: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Is the problem with the second statement?

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21129020/how-to-fix-unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte) solves your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the encoding while load.

Ex:

```
hist = pickle.load(f, encoding='utf-8') #or'latin1' or 'bytes'
```

Comment: Thank you so much. yes indeed.