# Python Unicode decode error- Not able to run script even after suggested correction

Tags: python

I am using `python 2.7.9`  to create excel sheet using tab delimited text files; however I am getting problem while running this python script

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    # encoding=utf8  
    import xlwt
    import os   
    import sys  
    reload(sys)  
    sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')


    wb = xlwt.Workbook()
    path = "/home/Final_analysis/"
    #print(os.listdir())
    lis = os.listdir(path)
    sheetnumber = 1
    for x in lis:
        if os.path.isfile(x)==True:
            extension = os.path.splitext(x)
            print(extension[1])
            if extension[1] == '.txt':
                #print("Yes")
                ws = wb.add_sheet(extension[0])
                row = 0
                column = 0
                a = open(x)

                while True:
                    a1 = a.readline()
                    if len(a1)==0:
                        break
                    data = a1.split("\t")
                    for z in data:
                        ws.write(row,column,z)
                        column += 1
                    column = 0
                    row += 1
                sheetnumber+=1
            else:
                pass
    wb.save("Ronic.xls")
```

I am getting following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "home/Final_analysis/combine_excel_v2.py", line 39, in <module>
    wb.save("Ronic.xls")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlwt/Workbook.py", line 710, in save
    doc.save(filename_or_stream, self.get_biff_data())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlwt/Workbook.py", line 674, in get_biff_data
    shared_str_table   = self.__sst_rec()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlwt/Workbook.py", line 636, in __sst_rec
    return self.__sst.get_biff_record()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlwt/BIFFRecords.py", line 77, in get_biff_record
    self._add_to_sst(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlwt/BIFFRecords.py", line 92, in _add_to_sst
    u_str = upack2(s, self.encoding)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlwt/UnicodeUtils.py", line 50, in upack2
    us = unicode(s, encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 83: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I have used answer given in thread  [How to fix: "UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21129020/how-to-fix-unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte/35444608)

But it didn't work.

problem is at `wb.save()` command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the encoding at the top of your program is to handle non-ascii characters in your *code*, not your *data*. `sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')` is not intended to be used in ordinary programs and does more harm than good.

To fix the problem, tell `xlwt` about the encoding to use.

Change this line:

```
wb = xlwt.Workbook()
```

to this:

```
wb = xlwt.Workbook(encoding="UTF-8")
```