# Replace 'alpha' and 'beta' to Greek characters in panda index names

Tags: python, pandas, latex, latin

[image]I'm using sns.clustermap to plot a dataframe from a panda dataframe. I want to replace all the instances of "alpha" and "beta" to the lowercase latin letters, but  I can't do it nomatter how I try. I tried to code it in Latex. Here is an example code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = [[1, 2], [3, 4]], index = ['5alpha-androstan-3beta,17alpha-diol disulfate', 'hippurate'])
df.index = df.iloc[:,0].index.str.replace('alpha', '$\alpha')
sns.clustermap(df)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Doing with `dict` passing to `replace`

```
df.index=df.index.to_series().replace({'alpha':'α',"beta":'β'},regex=True)
df
Out[664]: 
                                    0  1
5α-androstan-3β,17α-diol disulfate  1  2
hippurate                           3  4
```

Comment: I'm interested to replace alpha & beta to the Greek characters: α and β

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't work... I get rectangles instead of the Greek alpha or beta :
df.index = df.index.to_series().replace({'alpha':'α',"beta":'β'},regex=True)
df

Comment: @user1748101 this is jupyter problem , try with python gui

Answer (score 0):

So Now this works:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = [[1, 2], [3, 4]], index = ['5alpha-androstan-3beta,17alpha-diol disulfate', 'hippurate'])
df.index=df.index.to_series().replace({'alpha':'α',"beta":'β'},regex=True)
df
```

But I get the following error from clustermap:

"UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xce in position 24: ordinal not in range(128)"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21129020/how-to-fix-unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte

Comment: That solved it, thanks !!!!

import sys  

reload(sys)  
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')