# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x91 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128) in Spyder 3.3.2

Tags: python

I have problems when I want to load data from the pickle file. Can someone help me?

```
folder = 'WavfileDataset/IHaveADream'
GT_file = groundtruthfolder+os.sep+'GT_IHaveADream_'+tag+'.txt'

if feature_extraction:
    data1,test_files1_auto = get_features_per_song(folder,GT_file)

    output = open('data1_pitchGT.pkl', 'wb')
    pickle.dump(data1, output)
    output.close()

pkl_file = open('data1_pitchGT.pkl', 'rb') 
data1 = pickle.load(pkl_file)

GT1,test_files1 = get_onlyGT(folder, GT_file)
```

I get this error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x91 in position
>   1: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: you need to seeif the GT_file is correct format or not , and also need to provide line at which this error is coming

Comment: This question is addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21129020/how-to-fix-unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte)