# Decode Errors in pandas when trying to manupilate Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, encoding

I have a Excel sheet which I read using pd.read_excel() method. When I am trying to add new columns using my_frame['Test'] = my_frame['My Column'] it throws an error

Tried reading excel file in utf-8 format by using pd.read_excel('encoding'='utf-8') but it did not work.
The preprocess_price_file(temp_df) function produces a sliced dataframe and performs some pre-processing which includes dropping some NA rows.

```
prod_dfs = []
product_price_files = glob.glob('files/product_price/*.xlsx')
for c_file in product_price_files:
    temp_df = pd.read_excel(c_file,encoding = "utf-8")
    temp_df = self.preprocess_price_file(temp_df)
    prod_dfs.append(temp_df)
    prods_df = pd.concat(prod_dfs)
prods_df['Test'] = prods_df['My Column']
return prods_df
```

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf8 in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)

Answer (score 0):

I have ran across this issue before and this has helped: [How to fix: "UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21129020/how-to-fix-unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte).

Tl;dr version is that we cannot assume the incoming encoding, it's always better to be explicit rather than implicit.

If you need to find the native encoding, I try the following (probably not the most pythonic way):

`with open(<file path>, "r") as f:
    print(f)`

The output from the io.buffer will contain the file encoding.