# How to fix UnicodeDecodeError while fetching result from db in python?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am using a `postgres` database and connecting it using `psycopg2` connector. Here is my code below

```
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect(database=db, user=user, password=password, host=host, port=port)
cur = conn.cursor()

try:
    cur.execute(sql_query)
    result = cur.fetchall()
except Exception as e:
    print("Could not get results")
    conn.rollback()
```

Now the problem is I receive this error when I try to retrieve data from db

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/connection/dbaccess.py", line 119, in get_results_of_query
    result = cur.fetchall()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 20: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Now on looking up online, I found some posts where they asked to use `set_client_encoding('UTF8')`

So this is what I did

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(database=db, user=user, password=password, host=host, port=port)
cur = conn.cursor()
conn.set_client_encoding('UTF8')
```

And then I tried to run it again. But I still receive the same error like before. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the value of `sql_query` and what data is there in the data base?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix: "UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21129020/how-to-fix-unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte)