# I did python upgrade from 2.7 to python 3.5.2 , but gunicorn is not working in Linux 6.10 - 0 instances are running - failed

Tags: python, django, linux, upgrade, gunicorn

we upgraded virtual environment too ,
through svn revision number we updated all requirements we have both 2.7 and 3.5.2 python versions in the system .
is this making issue ?
when I see gunicorn tracelog we found below one

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 20: ordinal not in range(128)
[2020-02-13 15:39:22 +0000] [62014] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 62014)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 20: ordinal not in range(128)
[2020-02-13 15:39:22 +0000] [62007] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 62007)
[2020-02-13 15:39:22 +0000] [62002] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
```

Comment: please provide any answer on this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix: "UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21129020/how-to-fix-unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte)