# How to solve UnicodeDecode error in django

Tags: python, django

I was making a project but I accidentally deleted the git changes. The files were all lost but fortunately i recovered them using Recuva. The problem i am now facing is this, when i open the website, the first page shows up normally but the when i click that object to get its details, i get this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError at /cartoon/2
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 0: invalid start byte
```

can someone help me with this, thank you in advance

Comment: you need to share more codes and the full error stacktrace

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21129020/how-to-fix-unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte