# UnicodeDecodeError when I want to convert dbf files to csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dbf

I wrote a little program to convert dbf files to csv and it works on 80 % files.
When I try to convert whole folder I get error on last 2 dbf files.

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x88 in position 14: ordinal not in range(128)

This is my program:

```
import csv
from dbfread import DBF
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *
import os, sys
import glob


def dbf_to_csv(dbf_table_pth):#Input a dbf, output a csv, same name, same path, except extension
    csv_fn = dbf_table_pth[:-4]+ ".csv" #Set the csv file name
    table = DBF(dbf_table_pth)# table variable is a DBF object
    with open(csv_fn, 'w',encoding = 'utf-8', newline = '') as f:# create a csv file, fill it with dbf content
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(table.field_names)# write the column name
        for record in table:# write the rows
            writer.writerow(list(record.values()))
    return csv_fn# return the csv name
listOfFiles = []

def get_filenames():
    Tk().withdraw()
    print("Initializing Dialogue... \\nPlease select a file.")
    tk_filenames = filedialog.askdirectory()
    tempDir = tk_filenames
    return tempDir


choosen_dir = get_filenames()

os.chdir(choosen_dir)
for file in glob.glob("*.dbf"):
    listOfFiles.append(file)

for file in listOfFiles:
    dbf_to_csv(file)
```

Here I paste Trackback:

```text
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Pliki po Dawidzie\Converter\main.py", line 35, in <module>
    dbf_to_csv(file)

  File "C:\Pliki po Dawidzie\Converter\main.py", line 15, in dbf_to_csv
    for record in table:# write the rows

  File "C:\Users\maciej.olech\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\dbfread\dbf.py", line 314, in _iter_records
    items = [(field.name,

  File "C:\Users\maciej.olech\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\dbfread\dbf.py", line 315, in <listcomp>
    parse(field, read(field.length))) \

  File "C:\Users\maciej.olech\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\dbfread\field_parser.py", line 79, in parse
    return func(field, data)

  File "C:\Users\maciej.olech\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\dbfread\field_parser.py", line 87, in parseC
    return self.decode_text(data.rstrip(b'\0 '))

  File "C:\Users\maciej.olech\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\dbfread\field_parser.py", line 45, in decode_text
    return decode_text(text, self.encoding, errors=self.char_decode_errors)

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x88 in position 14: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Thanks for any help help.

Comment: Where exactly do you get the error (during reading the data, or somewhere else)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix: "UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21129020/how-to-fix-unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte)

Comment: Program convert 6 from 8 files correctly. Then he start to convert file number 7 and he crash.

Comment: Ok, but it didn't help us in helping you. Can you add the traceback to the question?