# Why is it that I am able to print out a good amount of lines until I reach a certain point. Once that point is reached I get an error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pythonista

So what I am basically trying to do is to read and print each individual line of an RTF file.  However, my problem is that with this code that I currently have it seems to do the job up until it reaches line 937. At that point it stops reading lines and gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~omz-software~Pythonista3/Documents/openFolders.py", line 8, in <module>
    for element in file:
  File "/var/containers/Bundle/Application/8F2965B6-AC1F-46FA-8104-6BB24F1ECB97/Pythonista3.app/Frameworks/Py3Kit.framework/pylib/encodings/ascii.py", line 27, in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 4250: ordinal not in range(128)
```

```
file = open("Steno Dictionary.rtf", "r")

#line_number is just to know what line number has been printed on the console.  
line_number = 1

for element in file:
    
    #print(line_number) prints until it reaches 937 and then the error occurs. 
    print(line_number)
    print(element)
    line_number +=1
```

How would I modify my current code to make it keep on reading lines until the end of the file? As there are still many more lines left.  I have searched high and low and cannot seem to figure it out!  Thank you very much to whoever can help me out! As a note: I’m using Pythonista on iOS.

Comment: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 4250` tells you that there's an unsupported character. Try another encoding, e.g: `file = open("Steno Dictionary.rtf", "r", encoding='utf-8')`. See [list of standard encodings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings)

Comment: Thanks a million! You definitely pointed me in the right direction.  The “utf-8” didn’t work.  So what I ended up doing was going the the link you provided with the list of standard encodings and tried a few… trying my best to make sense of it, ended up trying the “raw_unicode_escape” and it worked! Now I can read the entire file no problem!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix: "UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21129020/how-to-fix-unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting means that Python doesn't understand how to translate a specific character in the document using the default text encoding.

There are a few things you can try, the first is to check if explicitly setting the encoding to utf8 works.

```
file = open("Steno Dictionary.rtf", "r", encoding="utf-8")
...
```

if that doesn't work you can try to use other encodings or you can tell python to replace the bits it doesn't recognize with something else. like this

```
file = open("Steno Dictionary.rtf", "r", encoding="utf-8", errors="replace")
...
```

That will decode everything it knows how to, and replace what it doesn't with `?` characters.