# encode special characters python for csv output

Tags: python, csv, unicode

How can I get `csv.writer.writerow` to output á or è and other special characters along the same lines u, n....etc?

I am getting an error 
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xed' in position 37: ordinal not in range(128)

Have tried some of the suggestions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13512443/python-2-7-unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte) article with no avail

```
rowPrinter = []

while x < y:
     print "Data in at Line " + str(x + 1)
     rowPrinter.append([a[x], b[x], c[x]]])
     x = x + 1
```

x = 0

```
writer = csv.writer(outcsv, delimiter=',', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL, lineterminator='\n')
writer.writerow(['a', 'b', 'c'])
while x < y:
    print rowPrinter[x]
    writer.writerow(rowPrinter[x])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to encode all the data that you are trying to write:

```
writer.writerow([sub.encode("utf-8") for sub in rowPrinter[x]])
```

If you have a mixture of data:

```
writer.writerow([sub.encode("utf-8")  if isinstance(sub, basestring) else sub for sub in rowPrinter[x]])
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: @LucasCrostarosa, so you have a mixture of strings and ints?

Comment: yea, for example a is an int, b is a timestamp, and c is a string

Comment: Then the edit will work, you only want to encode the strings