# Python zipfile sending via suds error: "'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x8c in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)"

Tags: python, zip, ascii, suds

I have the following error when I trying to send Zipfile content via [suds](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/) method

```
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x8c in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Here is my code:

```
try:
    project_archive = open(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'zip/project.zip'), "rb")
    data = project_archive.read()
    client = Client(settings.UPLOAD_PROJECT_WS_URL)
    client.service.uploadProject(data)
except Exception as e:
    return HttpResponse(e)
else:
    return HttpResponse("Project was exported")
```

Comment: https://fedorahosted.org/suds/ticket/350  see the files there on how to do an attachment for suds I think ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suds doesn't support soap file attachment (not last time I checked, it has been a while).

Work around here:
https://fedorahosted.org/suds/attachment/ticket/350/soap_attachments.2.py

or use a different library

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that in the WSDL the argument type is `xsd:base64Binary`, you need to:

```
client.service.uploadProject(base64.b64encode(data))
```

In my case the sever was written in JAX-WS and the function argument type was `Byte[]` and Base64 worked for me

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be simply that you are trying to read a unicode formatted file using ascii codec. Refer to http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html for the official documentation on unicode. You can also look at [Unicode (UTF-8) reading and writing to files in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/491921/2423379) for a similar discussion.

In short for your problem the following code should work:

```
import codecs
project_archive = codecs.open(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'zip/project.zip'), 
                              "rb", "utf-8")
data = project_archive.read()
```

In the above solution its assumed that the unicode encoding used is `utf-8`. If some other codec (for example `ISO-8859-1`) is being used substitute that for the `utf-8`.