# Python encoding issue in reading from text file

Tags: python, encoding, python-2.7

I am reading a text file containing a single word `B\xc3\xa9zier`.

I wish to convert this to its equivalent decoded utf-8 form i.e. `Bézier` and print it to console.

My code is as follows:

```
foo=open("test.txt")  
for line in foo.readlines():  
    for word in line.split():  
        print(word.decode('utf-8'))
foo.close()
```

the output is:

```
B\xc3\xa9zier
```

However if i do something like this:

```
>>> print('B\xc3\xa9zier'.decode('utf-8'))
```

I get the correct output:

```
Bézier
```

I am unable to figure out why this is happening?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unicode (utf8) reading and writing to files in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491921/unicode-utf8-reading-and-writing-to-files-in-python)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems as though you have a raw utf8 escaped string in the file, use `string_escape` to decode it instead

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split():
            print(word.decode('string_escape').decode('utf-8'))


Bézier
```

Comment: Thanks for response .Could You please help me to figure out what is wrong with my code.

Comment: @Chauhan you should use `string_escape` encoding instead of `utf-8` because you want to unescape a unicode string, not decode utf8.

Comment: @jamylak Now I am getting BÃ©zier instead of Bézier

Comment: @Chauhan Then you need `word.decode('string_escape').decode('utf-8')`

Comment: @JanneKarila Thanks a lot .It works.Could you please explain it .

Comment: @Chauhan `decode('string_escape')` decodes the backslash escapes and gives you a utf-8 encoded string. jamylak is able to print it directly because his or her terminal uses utf-8 encoding.

Comment: You shouldn't `decode('utf8')` it right avay. Do this just before printing.

Comment: @kirelagin I would recommend decoding and working with unicode as long as possible.

Comment: @JanneKarila I'm sorry, you are right. I always get lost in those Python2 Unicode-related things =(.