# Make utf8 readable in a file

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I have dictionary of dictionary which has utf8 encoded keys. I am dumping this dictionary to a file using `json` module.
In the file keys are printed in utf8 format. Keys are actually letters of Bengali language.

I want actual letters to get written in the file. **How to do this ??**

If I print those keys(one of them is u'\u0982') to console actual letter(ং) is shown but in my file `\u0982`.is written. What does print do to show the actual letter?

Comment: This talks about unicode reading in python, not sure if it what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491921/unicode-utf8-reading-and-writing-to-files-in-python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are writing JSON; the JSON standard allows for `\uxxxx` escape sequences to encode non-ASCII characters. The Python `json` module uses this by default.

Switch off the feature by using the `ensure_ascii=False` switch when dumping the data:

```
json.dump(obj, yourfileobject, ensure_ascii=False)
```

This does mean that the output is no longer encoded to UTF-8 bytes as well; you'll need to use a `codecs.open()` managed file for this:

```
import json
import codecs

with codecs.open('/path/to/file', 'w', encoding='utf8') as output:
    json.dump(obj, output, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Now your unicode characters will be written to the file as UTF-8 encoded bytes instead. When opening the file with another program that *decodes* UTF-8 again, your codepoints should be displayed again as the same characters.

Comment: But I am getting this `'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u0982' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)` error when dump the data with `ensure_ascii=False`. This error is generated for the first key which is `\u0982` when I dump with default value i.e True

Comment: @knoxxs: mea culpa, indeed the `json.dump()` output then produces Unicode values and does *not* encode. Updated to include a method to write the data and have it encoded for you.

Answer (score 2):

use `ensure_ascii` parameter.

```
>>> import json
>>> print json.dumps(u'\u0982')
"\u0982"
>>> print json.dumps(u'\u0982', ensure_ascii=False)
"ং"
```

http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dump

> If ensure_ascii is True (the default), all non-ASCII characters in the
>   output are escaped with \uXXXX sequences, and the result is a str
>   instance consisting of ASCII characters only. If ensure_ascii is
>   False, some chunks written to fp may be unicode instances. ...