# How to open html file that contains Unicode characters?

Tags: python, python-2.7, character-encoding

I have html file called `test.html` it has one word `בדיקה`.

I open the test.html and print it's content  using this block of code:

```
file = open("test.html", "r")
print file.read()
```

but it prints `??????`, why this happened and how could I fix it?

BTW. when I open text file it works good.

Edit: I'd tried this:

```
>>> import codecs
>>> f = codecs.open("test.html",'r')
>>> print f.read()
?????
```

Comment: Read about unicode,UTF-8

Comment: You need to open you file in UTF-8 format. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491921/unicode-utf8-reading-and-writing-to-files-in-python

Comment: If it is still not working just post your page which you try to process.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

```
import codecs
f=codecs.open("test.html", 'r')
print f.read()
```

Try something like this.

Comment: also i try codecs.open("test.html",'r','utf-8') , but when I print f.read() I get unicode decode error !

Comment: I am using terminal !!

Comment: I got this error : UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe1 in position 0: invalid continuation byte

Comment: >>> import sys
>>> print sys.stdout.encoding
UTF-8

Comment: the file wasn't encoding utf-8 , it was windows-1255 !

Answer (score 26):

I encountered this problem today as well. I am using Windows and the system language by default is Chinese. Hence, someone may encounter this Unicode error similarly. Simply add `encoding = 'utf-8'`:

```
with open("test.html", "r", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    text= f.read()
```

Answer (score 17):

you can make use of the following code:

```
from __future__ import division, unicode_literals 
import codecs
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

f=codecs.open("test.html", 'r', 'utf-8')
document= BeautifulSoup(f.read()).get_text()
print(document)
```

If you want to delete all the blank lines in between and get all the words as a string (also avoid special characters, numbers) then also include:

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
docwords=word_tokenize(document)
for line in docwords:
    line = (line.rstrip())
    if line:
        if re.match("^[A-Za-z]*$",line):
            if (line not in stop and len(line)>1):
                st=st+" "+line
print st
```

*define `st` as a `string` initially, like `st=""`

Answer (score 8):

You can read HTML page using 'urllib'.

```
 #python 2.x

  import urllib

  page = urllib.urlopen("your path ").read()
  print page
```

Comment: how can i do operations on `page`. ? like reading particular words from it etc. Can i use `page` like a string?

Answer (score 6):

Use [codecs.open](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.open) with the encoding parameter.

```
import codecs
f = codecs.open("test.html", 'r', 'utf-8')
```

Answer (score 1):

CODE:

```
import codecs

path="D:\\Users\\html\\abc.html" 
file=codecs.open(path,"rb")
file1=file.read()
file1=str(file1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this

```
import requests

requests.get(url)
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use **'urllib'** in python3 same as

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27243244/4815313 with few changes.

```
#python3

import urllib

page = urllib.request.urlopen("/path/").read()
print(page)
```

Comment: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'request'`

Comment: @tommy.carstensen may be you should take a look at this [urllib python3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request)

Comment: Thanks. I'm quite familiar with that document. The indentation is wrong and it should be `import urllib.request`.