# Define a variable from a file in Python

Tags: python, file, variables, text

I'm trying to take a file that  have and take whatever number is on line one (and two and three, etc.) and assign them to a given variable. So say my file is just like:

```
1
5
6
1
```

So then how would I take line one and assign that value to variable_a within my code, then take line two and assign it to variable_b. Thanks!

Comment: First off, reading from a file: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unicode (utf8) reading and writing to files in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491921/unicode-utf8-reading-and-writing-to-files-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(fname) as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    numbers = [int(x) for x in content]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import string
fi = open(fname, "r")
vars = fi.read()
fi.close()

pos = 0
for i in vars.split("\n"):
    exec('variable_' + string.lowercase[pos] + '=' + i)
    pos += 1

print(variable_b) # will print 5
```