# Networkx : How to create graph edges from a csv file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, graph, networkx

I am trying to create a graph using networkx and so far I have created nodes from the following text files :
File 1(user_id.txt) sample data :

```
user_000001
user_000002
user_000003
user_000004
user_000005
user_000006
user_000007
```

File 2(user_country.txt) sample data : contains few blank lines too in case if user didn't enter his country details

```
 Japan
 Peru
 United States

 Bulgaria
 Russian Federation
 United States
```

File 3(user_agegroup.txt) data : contains four age groups

```
 [12-18],[19-25],[26-32],[33-39]
```

I have other two files with following sample data for adding edges in the graph

File 4(id,agegroup.txt)

```
user_000001,[19-25]
user_000002,[19-25]
user_000003,[33-39]
user_000004,[19-25]
user_000005,[19-25]
user_000006,[19-25]
user_000007,[26-32]
```

File 5(id,country.txt)

```
(user_000001,Japan)
(user_000002,Peru)
(user_000003,United States)
(user_000004,)
(user_000005,Bulgaria)
(user_000006,Russian Federation)
(user_000007,United States)
```

So far I have written following code to draw graphs with only nodes: 
(Please check the code because `print g.number_of_nodes()`
 never prints correct no. of nodes though `print g.nodes()`shows correct no. of nodes.)

```
import csv
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
g=nx.Graph()

#extract and add AGE_GROUP nodes in graph
f1 = csv.reader(open("user_agegroup.txt","rb"))
for row in f1: 
    g.add_nodes_from(row)
    nx.draw_circular(g,node_color='blue')

#extract and add COUNTRY nodes in graph
f2 = csv.reader(open('user_country.txt','rb'))
for row in f2:
    g.add_nodes_from(row) 
    nx.draw_circular(g,node_color='red')

#extract and add USER_ID nodes in graph
f3 = csv.reader(open('user_id.txt','rb'))
for row in f3:
    g.add_nodes_from(row)
    nx.draw_random(g,node_color='yellow')

print g.nodes()
plt.savefig("path.png")
print g.number_of_nodes()
plt.show()
```

Besides this I can't figure out how to add edges from file4 and file5. Any help with code for that is appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: What are the values that appear for g.nodes and g.number_of_nodes and what did you expect ?

Comment: I get 160 as no. of nodes rather than 259 which is the actual no.of nodes in three files(file 1, 2 and 3) and g.node is printing nodes which when I counted turned out to be correct i.e 259. Again, any suggestions regarding code for creating edges?

Comment: So, for the sample you provided, you expect to obtain 18 nodes ?

Comment: As for adding edges, you can read row then use G.add_edge(row[0],row[1])

Comment: `g.number_of_nodes` just returns the length of `g.node` (internally, a dictionary), and g.nodes() also just returns `g.node`. So unless you are modifying the graph between checking `len(g.nodes())` and `g.number_of_nodes)` it is hard to see how these two will do anything different.  Are all of the entries in these three files all unique? Any duplicates will correspond to the same node. ([dict docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries))

Comment: @Bonlenfum Out of File 1, 2 and 3, File 2 surely has duplicates as I made it clear with the sample data I provided in my question. Though, your point is valid. However, @Abdallah's solution produces correct result for `g,number_of_nodes` and `g.number_of_edges` as well.

Comment: Fair point, I should have noticed the duplicate countries. The issue that you have with weird country names might just be to do with special characters. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/844443 for how to read in utf8, for instance.  Anyway, the solution provided is nice to see

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For simplification I made user ID's [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] in the user_id.txt and id,country.txt files. You have some problems in your code:

1- First you add some nodes to the graph (for instance from the user_id.txt file) then you draw it, then you add some other nodes to the graph from another file then you re-draw the whole graph again on the same figure. So, in the end you have many graph in one figure.

2- You used the draw_circular method to draw twice, that is why the blue nodes never appeared as they are overwritten by the 'red' nodes.

I have made some changes to your code to draw only one time in the end. And to draw nodes with the needed colors, I added an attribute called colors when adding nodes. Then I used this attribute to build a color map which I sent to draw_networkx function.
Finally, adding edges was a bit tricky because of the empty field in the id,country.txt so I had to remove empty nodes before creating the graph. Here is the code and the figure that appears afterwards.

```
G=nx.Graph()

#extract and add AGE_GROUP nodes in graph
f1 = csv.reader(open("user_agegroup.txt","rb"))
for row in f1: 
    G.add_nodes_from(row, color = 'blue')

#extract and add COUNTRY nodes in graph
f2 = csv.reader(open('user_country.txt','rb'))
for row in f2:
    G.add_nodes_from(row, color = 'red') 

#extract and add USER_ID nodes in graph
f3 = csv.reader(open('user_id.txt','rb'))
for row in f3:
    G.add_nodes_from(row, color = 'yellow')

f4 = csv.reader(open('id,agegroup.txt','rb'))
for row in f4:
    if len(row) == 2 : # add an edge only if both values are provided
        G.add_edge(row[0],row[1])

f5 = csv.reader(open('id,country.txt','rb'))

for row in f5:
    if len(row) == 2 : # add an edge only if both values are provided
        G.add_edge(row[0],row[1])
# Remove empty nodes
for n in G.nodes():
    if n == '':
        G.remove_node(n)
# color nodes according to their color attribute
color_map = []
for n in G.nodes():
    color_map.append(G.node[n]['color'])
nx.draw_networkx(G, node_color = color_map, with_labels = True, node_size = 500)

plt.savefig("path.png")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @Abdallah Sobehy. This is very helpful. By adapting this code I am now able to add edges read from the file into graph. But I think there is a little syntax error in line : `color_map.append(G.node[n]['color']) `which is why control doesn't go past that `for` loop so no graphical output there. `print g.nodes` and `print g.edges` prints correct list of nodes and edges so that means code is correct until that error line. Can you please confirm if there wasn't any error in your code so I can go ahead and accept your answer?

Comment: `draw_networkx` doesn't work either. I changed that to `draw_random` and it worked. Similarly, `draw_circular` works too.

Comment: EDIT : `nx.draw_networkx(G, node_color = color_map, with_labels = True, node_size = 500)` doesn't work either. I changed that to `nx.draw_random(g)` and it worked. Similarly, `nx.draw_circular(g)` works too.  But it draws default red colored nodes without labels...I am guessing something is wrong with `node_color = color_map, with_labels = True`. Please edit your answer if you happen to fix these issues.

Comment: Before i posted the answer, I ran the code and it was fine. I can not verify now because I do not have my machine right now. Anyways, just a small check, I named the graph to **G** instead of **g**. Check that you use the graph name correctly and let me know

Comment: Yeah, I took care of **G** in my code. I think I have fixed the problem. I dig into the whole dataset I ran the code on and found out few 'weird' country names. Also the whole thing was messed up in few rows. I deleted them. That fixed the issue of labels not showing up for nodes in graph. But I still have no idea why it throws an error when I add `with_labels = true` parameter in `nx.draw_networkx`. When, I removed this parameter and ran the code again. Surprisingly it worked anyway and labels also showed up. Ah, I'll just let it be like that.

Comment: It is a bit weird yes, but if it is working for the moment you can continue with it. And if something happens you can always comment here or ask another  question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for like:

```
for a,b in df_edges.iterrows():
    G.add_edges_from([(b['source'], b['target'])])
```