# How to write Chinese characters to file by python

Tags: python

I'm walking through a directory and want to write all files names into a file.  Here's the piece of code

```
with open("c:/Users/me/filename.txt", "a") as d:
   for dir, subdirs, files in os.walk("c:/temp"):
      for f in files:
         fname = os.path.join(dir, f)
         print fname
         d.write(fname + "\n")
d.close()
```

The problem I have is, there are some files that are named in Chinese characters.  By using `print`, I can see the file name correctly in console, but in the target file, it's just a mess...  I've tried to open the file like `open(u"c:/Users/me/filename.txt", "a")`, but it did not work.  I also tried to write `fname.decode("utf-16")`, still does not work...

Comment: `fname.encode('utf8')`

Comment: @TimPietzcker I think the Chinese characters are in the filename. :-)

Comment: As a tip, if you can use/install python3, just do it… the problem might go away magically!

Comment: Python 3x versions supports unicode characters. So use 3x versions.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491921/unicode-utf8-reading-and-writing-to-files-in-python) question has details on how to prepare your file for UTF.

Answer (score 3):

In Python 2, it's a good idea to use `codecs.open()` if you're dealing with encodings other than ASCII. That way, you don't need to manually encode everything you write. Also, `os.walk()` should be passed a Unicode string if you're expecting non-ASCII characters in the filenames:

```
import codecs
with codecs.open("c:/Users/me/filename.txt", "a", encoding="utf-8") as d:
   for dir, subdirs, files in os.walk(u"c:/temp"):
      for f in files:
         fname = os.path.join(dir, f)
         print fname
         d.write(fname + "\n")
```

No need to call `d.close()`, the `with` block already takes care of that.

Comment: Error raised..  `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd6 in position 8: ordinal not in range(128)`

Answer (score 2):

Use [`str.encode()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) to encode `fname` before you write it to the file:

```
d.write(fname.encode('utf8') + '\n')
```

Comment: doesn't not work.  `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd6 in position 8: ordinal not in range(128)`.  I think the reason is the string is already encoded?

Answer (score 2):

The key is to tell python to **prepare** the file for being used in "utf-8" format. I wonder why python doesn't assume **utf-8** by default. Anyway, try the following:

```
with open("c:/Users/me/filename.txt", "a", encoding='utf-8') as d:
    for dir, subdirs, files in os.walk("c:/temp"):
        ...
```

I am using python3.5. So, please be aware that the "encoding" option may be not available in python 2.7. But the idea is to tell python in advance about the encoding, rather than fighting with encoding of each string later.

Answer (score 2):

To succesfully write chinese characters in python 2 you have to do the following.

1. Open the file using the codecs library which allows you to provide
   the encoding parameter and set it to unicode.
2. Write the string in
   unicode encoding.

The **corrected** code would be the following:

```
import codecs

with codecs.open("c:/Users/me/filename.txt", "a", encoding='utf-8') as d:
    for dir, subdirs, files in os.walk("c:/temp"):
        for f in files:
            fname = os.path.join(dir, f)
            print fname
            d.write(fname.decode('utf-8') + "\n")
```

#### Note

The same problem does not exist in python 3 so you should also consider making your script python 3 compatible.

Answer (score 1):

with open("xyz.xml', "w", encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
worked for me.

Comment: with open("xyz.xml', "a", encoding='utf-8-sig') as f: worked for me