# Print Unicode string containing both accented characters and emoticons

Tags: python, utf-8, emoticons

I'm reading a file with Python that contains exactly the following line

```
à è ì ò ù ç @ \U0001F914
```

where `\U0001F914` is the unicode code for an emoticon.

if interpret the string as

`string=string.decode('utf-8')`

I get:

`à è ì ò ù ç @ \U0001F914`

while if I interpret as following:

`string=string.decode('unicode-escape')`

I get:

`Ã  Ã¨ Ã¬ Ã² Ã¹ Ã§ @`

How can I print instead:

`à è ì ò ù ç @`

I'm a beginner, so pardon me if my question is stupid, but I can't get it out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/844443/2083770)

Comment: How can I make it work? I'm a newbie...:'(

Comment: What happens if you just `print string`? How about `print repr(string)`?

Comment: if i print string `à è ì ò ù \U0001F914`

Comment: if I print repr(string)     `   '\xc3\xa0 \xc3\xa8 \xc3\xac \xc3\xb2 \xc3\xb9 \\U0001F914'   `

Comment: print repr(string)   `'\xc3\xa0 \xc3\xa8 \xc3\xac \xc3\xb2 \xc3\xb9 \\U0001F914'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it is not the best solution but first you can use `encode` with `'unicode-escape'` instead of `decode` and you get

```
data = 'à è ì ò ù ç @ \U0001F914'
print data.encode('unicode-escape')

\xe0 \xe8 \xec \xf2 \xf9 \xe7 @ \\U0001F914
```

then you have to replace `\\` with `\` - in Python you will need `\\\\` and `\\`

```
data = 'à è ì ò ù ç @ \U0001F914'
print data.encode('unicode-escape').replace('\\\\', '\\')

\xe0 \xe8 \xec \xf2 \xf9 \xe7 @ \U0001F914
```

and then you can use your `decode` with `'unicode-escape'`

```
data = 'à è ì ò ù ç @ \U0001F914'
print data.encode('unicode-escape').replace('\\\\', '\\').decode('unicode-escape')

à è ì ò ù ç @
```

---

**EDIT:**

It seems you have to add `.decode('utf-8')` at the beginning

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

data = 'à è ì ò ù ç @ \U0001F914'.decode('utf-8')

result = data.encode('unicode-escape').replace('\\\\', '\\').decode('unicode-escape')

print result  #.encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: I get `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: which code - first, second or third. Assing result to variable and then print variable to see if problem is with encode/decode or with print. your console/terminal may use unknow encodind and python doesn't know how to encode text (when you use `print()`) so it use `ascii` encoding.

Comment: my (your) code as it is written in my editor: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`
`data = 'à è ì ò ù \U0001F914'`
`print data.encode('unicode-escape')`
`print data.encode('unicode-escape').replace('\\\\', '\\')`
`print data.encode('unicode-escape').replace('\\\\', '\\').decode('unicode-escape')`

Comment: And I get error at line 3 where it says `print data.encode('unicode-escape')` Error is ` File "sticker.py", line 3, in <module>
    print data.encode('unicode-escape')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: you need only `data=` and last `print`. Problem is console/terminal which doesn't inform Python what endcoding it uses so `print` use `.encode('ascii')` as default. You may use `.encode('utf-8')` if your console/terminal use `utf-8` to display text. If you use WIndows then you probably will need `.encode('cp1250')` or similar.

Comment: If I write in my source code file only data= and last print I get nevertheless `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: Can you reproduce your solution on your machine?

Comment: if I limit myself at print data I get `à è ì ò ù \U0001F914`

Comment: take note that in the file I'm trying to read it is not present an emoticon when I open it. instead it contains a \ then a U then a 0...... then a 1 then an F.. which are Ascii. I want to interpret the sequence \U0001F914 as an emoticon but when I successfully do it, then I can't read the accented characters....

Comment: I run Linux Mint (based on Ubuntu 14.04) and I use Python 2.7.12 and I don't have this problem when I run `python script.py` in bash console

Comment: Try `data = 'à è ì ò ù ç @ \U0001F914'.decode('utf-8')`

Comment: THANKS! It works! Accepted as right answer, upvoted and I want to hug you via internet ;). You made my day. Next time I promise I will study the reference instead of copy-pasting without knowing. thanks again.

Comment: `decode/encode` always makes problem :) I send you `\U0001F914`  - whatever it is :)

Answer (score 0):

\U0001F914 is outside of the printable range for IDLE, Tk, and most terminals.

Comment: My terminal (bash) correctly interpret \U0001F914 as an emoticon and displays it correctly on screen.