# codecs.open(utf-8) fails to read plain ASCII file

Tags: python, python-2.7, utf-8, readline, codec

I have a plain ASCII file. When I try to open it with `codecs.open(..., "utf-8")`, I am unable to read single characters. ASCII is a subset of UTF-8, so why can't `codecs` open such a file in UTF-8 mode?

```
# test.py

import codecs

f = codecs.open("test.py", "r", "utf-8")

# ASCII is supposed to be a subset of UTF-8:
# http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/utf8.htm

assert len(f.read(1)) == 1 # OK
f.readline()
c = f.read(1)
print len(c)
print "'%s'" % c
assert len(c) == 1 # fails

# max% p test.py
# 63
# '
# import codecs
#
# f = codecs.open("test.py", "r", "utf-8")
#
# # ASC'
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "test.py", line 15, in <module>
#     assert len(c) == 1 # fails
# AssertionError
# max%
```

system:

```
Linux max 4.4.0-89-generic #112~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Aug 1 22:08:32 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Of course it works with regular `open`. It also works if I remove the `"utf-8"` option. Also what does `63` mean? That's like the middle of the 3rd line. I don't get it.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't reading 0 characters?

Comment: @Ignacio I added more debug to show that in fact I'm getting 63 characters. This is exactly what I saw in the real-system example originally too.

Comment: Also print out the character itself, not just the length, and the byte code for the character.

Comment: The length suggests it includes the previous readline result as well; interesting.

Comment: @Evert Yes, very interesting indeed! It seems to be reading *starting* at the right spot, but it grabs the wrong number of characters (63 vs. 1). Also, by the way, `f.tell()` seems just as unreliable. Also come to think of it, in my last example it was off by 57 and the `readline()` was a little longer. Seems like it could be grabbing `(72? - len(readline())`... but why?

Comment: Well, at least I can reproduce this on my Mac, with Python versions 2.7.10, 2.7.13 and 3.6.2. `len(c)` for me is 59 in all cases.

Comment: It likely is an issue with `readline()`, since (from the docs): "Files are always opened in binary mode, even if no binary mode was specified. This is done to avoid data loss due to encodings using 8-bit values. This means that no automatic conversion of '\n' is done on reading and writing.".

Comment: Side-note: *Never* use `codecs.open`. It's buggy in weird ways (as @Evert notes, it has to open files in binary mode, which has all sorts of side-effects). Try [using `io.open` instead](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open) (it's the same as plain `open` on Py3, and provides the same interface on Py2), and is both faster and more correct than `codecs.open` (which is essentially deprecated). I suspect your problem will disappear.

Comment: @Evert. Hmm. I wouldn't think '\n' would need to be converted here, since it is both the actual value in the file and the value that `readline()` is searching for. Also I checked the `readline()` *result* and it looks fine... but perhaps it is having a side-effect. If I change `readline()` to `read(9)` then it works. I agree that the `readline()` would be suspect here, as it probably reads ahead several characters to work efficiently.

Comment: @ShadowRanger yeah the `io.open()` is working better, even with the `utf-8` option. OK so yeah maybe can we find some good references on the deprecation/bugginess of `codecs`? I would accept that.

Comment: @personal_clown: `codecs.open` is in a weird state. It's strictly inferior to `io.open` except in some very unusual cases (bytes<->bytes codecs like ROT13 and hex, as opposed to the standard bytes<->Unicode codecs). Because of the weirdo use cases, they've been reluctant to officially deprecate it, but if you check the Python bug tracker, it's often referred to as pseudo-deprecated. [PEP 400 includes a bunch of reasons](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0400/#streamreader-and-streamwriter-issues) why `StreamReader`/`StreamWriter`/`StreamReaderWriter` (what `codecs.open` creates) are broken.

Comment: Interesting that `f.read(1)` reads a whole line.  I got the same results on Windows, but if I *only* do `f.read(1)` or *only* `f.readline()` on the whole file they work fine.  It seems to be an interaction when you mix them.

Comment: @ShadowRanger and Mark yes this looks an awful lot like [issue 8260](https://bugs.python.org/issue8260), doesn't it? OK I'll accept that as an answer. Thank you.

Comment: @personal_clown: Heh, I'd found that bug a little bit ago, and it sent me down the rabbit hole that led to my answer. That bug seems to be fixing specific symptoms of the problem I describe, but fundamentally, it's an incompability between the definitions of `size` used by `StreamReaderWriter` and `StreamReader`.

Comment: `StreamReader`... I see. But it looked and quacked like a `file`!!! And now `io` is neither a `file` nor a `StreamReader`. Interesting. Yeah, the real bug is that they made something that was *almost* a `file`, and yet had the argument order mixed up. Thank you for your help.

Comment: General advice: Stay *away* from `codecs.open()`. Use `io.open()` to use the far better Python 3 I/O implementation backported to Python 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found your problem:

When passed an encoding, `codecs.open` returns a `StreamReaderWriter`, which is really just a wrapper around (*not* a subclass of; it's a "composed of" relationship, not inheritance) `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter`. Problem is:

1. `StreamReaderWriter` provides a "normal" `read` method (that is, it takes a `size` parameter and that's it)
2. It delegates to the internal [`StreamReader.read` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.StreamReader.read), where the `size` argument is only a hint as to the number of bytes to read, but not a limit; the *second* argument, `chars`, is a strict limiter, but `StreamReaderWriter` never passes that argument along (it doesn't accept it)
3. When `size` hinted, but not capped using `chars`, if `StreamReader` has buffered data, and it's large enough to match the `size` hint `StreamReader.read` blindly returns the contents of the buffer, rather than limiting it in any way based on the `size` hint (after all, only `chars` imposes a *maximum* return size)

The API of `StreamReader.read` and the meaning of `size`/`chars` for the API is the only documented thing here; the fact that `codecs.open` returns `StreamReaderWriter` is not contractual, nor is the fact that `StreamReaderWriter` wraps `StreamReader`, I just used `ipython`'s `??` magic to read the source code of the `codecs` module to verify this behavior. But documented or not, that's what it's doing (feel free to read the source code for `StreamReaderWriter`, it's all Python level, so it's easy).

The best solution is to switch to `io.open`, which is faster and more correct in every standard case (`codecs.open` supports the weirdo codecs that don't convert between `bytes` [Py2 `str`] and `str` [Py2 `unicode`], but rather, handle `str` to `str` or `bytes` to `bytes` encodings, but that's an incredibly limited use case; most of the time, you're converting between `bytes` and `str`). All you need to do is import `io` instead of `codecs`, and change the `codecs.open` line to:

```
f = io.open("test.py", encoding="utf-8")
```

The rest of your code can remain unchanged (and will likely run faster to boot).

As an alternative, you could explicitly bypass `StreamReaderWriter` to get the `StreamReader`'s `read` method and pass the limiting argument directly, e.g. change:

```
c = f.read(1)
```

to:

```
# Pass second, character limiting argument after size hint
c = f.reader.read(6, 1)  # 6 is sort of arbitrary; should ensure a full char read in one go
```

I suspect [Python Bug #8260](https://bugs.python.org/issue8260), which covers intermingling `readline` and `read` on `codecs.open` created file objects, applies here, officially, it's "fixed", but if you read the comments, the fix wasn't complete (and may not be possible to complete given the documented API); arbitrarily weird combinations of `read` and `readline` will be able to break it.

Again, just use `io.open`; as long as you're on Python 2.6 or higher, it's available, and it's just plain better.

Comment: Yeah, I really only started seeing my problems right after I started mixing `readline` and `read`. Must be the 8260 as you say. Thanks for all the helpful research. I'll take a closer look at `io` and other options.

Comment: @personal_clown: Yeah, `readline` causes the problem because, to avoid excessive system call overhead, it buffers (72 bytes IIRC). If you just performed `read(1)` calls, it would read one byte at a time without buffering (because you "hinted" you only needed a byte and it trusts the hint); you'd never get in a position where `size` vs. `chars` mattered. But `readline` prepopulates the buffer, so now `size` without `chars` means roughly "return greater of current buffer or `size` bytes worth of characters".