# How to print current columns and to be lowercase without punctuation in CSV file?

Tags: python, regex, csv

I have little code which using `regex` and here I'm trying to make my records to be with lowercase and without any punctuations in it, but in further situation I have error

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 5387: character maps to `<undefined>`

I want to extract `Record ID` and `Title` for the records with `Languages` English

```py
import csv
import re
import numpy

filename = ('records.csv')

def reg_test(name):

    reg_result = ''

    with open(name, 'r') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)

        for row in reader:
            row = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', str(row))
            reg_result += row + ','

            if (row['Languages'] == 'English')
                return reg_result

print(reg_test(filename).lower())
```

Comment: Can you add `records.csv` content?

Comment: post a testable fragment from your csv

Comment: Seems to be a problem with your CSV file at position 5387, maybe there is some symbol not present in the current character map (maybe Cyrillic, Chinese, or something like that). You could print the line before the error and then check your CSV file for some strange characters.

Comment: https://i.postimg.cc/Gm37GGjW/Capture.jpg

Comment: You might need to set the encoding on your streams. Assuming the file is in utf-8, this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/844443/3216427 . Or you might need to add the `encoding` parameter to the `open()` call, as in the examples at https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: Аctually if i try to type a code without `regex` and print the current columns, there is no problem. The problem it comes when I try to use `regex` to make it lowercase without any punctuations.

Comment: @KirilVodenicharov, instead of guessing you could just post a  testable fragment and expected result - so that you will increase your chances to get a quick and workable answer

Comment: What are your locale settings, by the way?

Comment: In any case, as others have said, if you could post a small csv file that exhibits the problem, maybe with just a line or two in it, we'll be able to test on our machines. Right now, all we can do is guess and it's unlikely anyone will be able to solve this for you without a test file.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re, csv

# sample.csv - contains some samples from original csv file.
with open('sample.csv', 'rb') as f:
    patt = r'[:;\'".`~!@#$?-_*()=\[\]\/]+'
    puncs = re.findall(patt, f.read())
    f.close()

with open('sample.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)    # leaving the header of csv file
    data = []
    for row in reader:
        data.append(row)
    f.close()

new_data = []

for i, j in enumerate(data):
    d = ','.join(j)
    nop = [c for c in d if c not in puncs]
    nop = ''.join(nop)

    new_data.append(nop.split(','))

print new_data
```

output:

```
[['UkEN000561198', 'article', 'text', '00310182', '', 'QE500', '56045', 'Mesozoic radiolarian biostratigraphy of Japan and collage tectonics along the eastern continental margin of Asia', '', 'Kojima', ' S  Mizutani', ' S', '', 'Netherlands', 'PALAEOGEOGRAPHY PALAEOCLIMATOLOGY PALAEOECOLOGY', 'monthly', '1992', '96', '2Jan', '', '', '', '367', '', 'PALAEOGEOGRAPHY PALAEOCLIMATOLOGY PALAEOECOLOGY 9612', ' 367 1992', '634345'],
['UkEN001027396', 'article', 'text', '03778398', '', 'QE719', '560', 'Late Pliocene climate in the Southeast Atlantic Preliminary results from a multidisciplinary study of DSDP Site 532', '', 'Hall', ' M A  Heusser', ' L  Sancetta', ' C', '', 'Netherlands', 'MARINE MICROPALAEONTOLOGY', '4 issues per year', '1992', '20', '1', '', '', '', '59', '', 'MARINE MICROPALAEONTOLOGY 201', ' 59 1992', '53764']]
```

Hope, this may help.

Comment: pass the `row` inside `.findall()` as string, str(row).

Comment: [![Capture.jpg](https://i.postimg.cc/qqqnpcHT/Capture.jpg)](https://postimg.cc/dZMDBy0H) take a look...

Comment: Still not working and the `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str

Comment: where do you get the TypeError...? and there's no need to use `reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)` as it can be opened using the`open()` func. and there it'll works fine. It'll help a lot if u provide a content sample of your `.csv` file. That we can test on.