# Yaml safe load special character ° from file

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I am trying to read a yml config file using PyYAML. See below example of such a file. The desired field may contain a special character, such as `°`. The resulting string in below example is not the desired `°C`, but rather `Â°C`.

The goal is to only read `°C`. I have control over the config file, so escaping or quoting is not a problem. Also decoding, replacing or other operations afterwards are possible, but they should also work for strings without special characters and strings with other special characters.

So far I had no success down this road however.

## Example

*test.yml*

```
super_important_variable: °C
```

*Code*

```
import yaml
with open('test.yml', 'r') as open_yml:
    print(yaml.safe_load(open_yml))
```

*Current result*

```
{'super_important_variable': 'Â°C'}
```

*Desired result*

```
{'super_important_variable': '°C'}
```

The weird thing is that this returns the correct result:

```
import yaml
yml_str = "super_important_variable: °C"
yaml.safe_load(yml_str)

> {'super_important_variable': '°C'}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
import yaml
with open('test.yaml', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as open_yml:
    print(yaml.safe_load(open_yml))
```

> More here about encoding and files in python: [Unicode (UTF-8) reading and writing to files in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491921/unicode-utf-8-reading-and-writing-to-files-in-python)