# Gettin non-english text from html doc

Tags: python, html, utf-8

I'm trying to get a title of html document in python, but getting weird symbols. I guess that's because of encoding, but the html doc in utf-8 encoding.
**Is there any way I can get normal letters?**

Here is code and what am I getting:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

 with open("index.html") as file:
     src = file.read()


soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml")

title = soup.title.text

print(title)
```

`Р“Р»Р°РІРЅР°СЏ СЃС‚СЂР°РЅРёС†Р°`

Comment: can you paste your code here?

Comment: i posted code of a program or do you mean code og html doc?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491921/unicode-utf-8-reading-and-writing-to-files-in-python

Comment: try : `with open("index.html", encoding="utf-8") as file:`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to specify an encoding type when opening the file:

```py
 with open("index.html", encoding='utf-8') as file:
     src = file.read()
```

Comment: yeah thanks, that helped, feeling kind of stupid now, because of how simple the answer was

Comment: _Learning is a lifelong process_ ~ keep trying and you will keep getting better :)