# styling Tab title text in ipywidgets

Tags: python, ipywidgets

Is it possible to style the title of a tab in ipywidgets?
Using the [docs example](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Widget%20List.html#tabs), is it possible to set a style for the tabs 0-4 either individually or as a collective?

```
tab_contents = ['P0', 'P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P4']
children = [widgets.Text(description=name) for name in tab_contents]
tab = widgets.Tab()
tab.children = children
tab.titles = [str(i) for i in range(len(children))]
tab
```

There is no `style` attribute for the `Tab()`, and options for `tab.titles` are `['count', 'index']`
The [styling of widgets](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Widget%20Styling.html) is related to widgets themselves rather than the containers they are in.

Answer (score 0):

So it is possible, but it is still beyond me right at this minute in a succinct python solution.
The error when you submit something other than text to the widget is:

```
TraitError: The 'titles' trait of a Tab instance contains an Unicode of a TypedTuple which expected a unicode string, ...
```

Creating a unicode string with characters is possible, e.g. [here](https://#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491921/unicode-utf-8-reading-and-writing-to-files-in-python)

I managed to get styled title text by using an online unicode generator in the style I was after, and pasting that into the jupyter notebook.

Its not a great solution, happy for anyone to put a unicode solution in laypersons terms!