# Python and parsing unicode files

Tags: python, parsing, unicode, file-io, csv

A few weeks ago I wrote a CSV parser in python and it was working great with the provided text file. But when we tried to test is with other files the problems started.

First was the

> ValueError: empty string for float()

for a string like "313.44". The problem was that in unicode there was some empty bytes betwee the numbers '\x0'.

Ok I decoded to read it as an unicode with

> codecs.open(filename, 'r', 'utf-16')

And then the hell opened, missing BOM, problems with the line end characters (LF vs CR+LF) etc.

So can you provide me or give me hint for a workaround about parsing unicode and non-unicode files if I do not know what the encoding is, is BOM present, what line ending are etc.

P.S. I am using Python 2.7

Comment: Why are you writing a csv parser and not just using the `csv` module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved using the csv module as proposed by Daenyth

Answer (score 0):

It mainly depends on the Python version you are using but those 2 links shopuld help you out:

- http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html
- [Character reading from file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147741/character-reading-from-file-in-python)