# decoding/encoding strings, submiting 'Šiven' but getting '\xa6iven'

Tags: python, string, encoding, decoding

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS, Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:09:56)

```
>>> m = 'Šiven'
>>> m
'\xa6iven'
>>> unicode(m)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xa6 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How should I properly set it (encoding, decoding) so that it writes exactly what it reads?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Python 2.x, single quotes denote a string of **bytes**, not characters. You want a **character** string, which is prefixed with `u` in 2.x:

```
>>> m = u'Šiven'
>>> print(m)
Šiven
>>> m.encode('utf-8') # Get the corresponding UTF-8 bytestring
'\xc5\xa0iven'
```

Note that this only works if your terminal encoding matches your platform's encoding. You should really just set both to UTF-8.

If that's not the case, you should use unicode escapes:

```
>>> m = u'\u0160iven'
>>> print(m)
Šiven
>>> m.encode('utf-8')
'\xc5\xa0iven'
```

In a Python file (not a terminal), you can set the encoding according to [PEP 263](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) by starting the file like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

You may also want to use Python 3.x, which clears up the confusion between byte and character strings.

Comment: m is from somehing like this M=file.readlines() ... for m in M: ... how can i state in there this: m = u'Šiven' ?

Comment: You don't need the `readlines` in there, you can just iterate over the file (and that will halve your memory requirements). You should really consult [other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491921/unicode-utf8-reading-and-writing-to-files-in-python) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147741/character-reading-from-file-in-python), or, if these questions (and the ones you have searched for) and their top answers don't solve your problem, ask a new question yourself. In short, use [`codecs.open`](http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html#codecs.open).

Answer (score 0):

You probably should put `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` and use editors and everything else in utf-8 mode anyway to avoid these problems, but if you want to find out which encoding suits your current input best, you could try this script (replace `'some string'` with something more localized):

```
encodings = ['ascii', 'cp037', 'cp424', 'cp437', 'cp500', 'cp720', 'cp737', 'cp775', 'cp850', 'cp852', 'cp855', 'cp856', 'cp857', 'cp858', 'cp860', 'cp861', 'cp862', 'cp863', 'cp864', 'cp865', 'cp866', 'cp869', 'cp874', 'cp875', 'cp932', 'cp949', 'cp950', 'cp1006', 'cp1026', 'cp1140', 'cp1250', 'cp1251', 'cp1252', 'cp1253', 'cp1254', 'cp1255', 'cp1256', 'cp1257', 'cp1258', 'latin_1', 'iso8859_2', 'iso8859_3', 'iso8859_4', 'iso8859_5', 'iso8859_6', 'iso8859_7', 'iso8859_8', 'iso8859_9', 'iso8859_10', 'iso8859_13', 'iso8859_14', 'iso8859_15', 'iso8859_16', 'johab', 'koi8_r', 'koi8_u', 'mac_cyrillic', 'mac_greek', 'mac_iceland', 'mac_latin2', 'mac_roman', 'mac_turkish', 'ptcp154', 'utf_32', 'utf_32_be', 'utf_32_le', 'utf_16', 'utf_16_be', 'utf_16_le', 'utf_7', 'utf_8', 'utf_8_sig']

def test(s):
    for enc in encodings:
        try:
            u = unicode(s, enc)
            print u, enc
        except: pass

test('some string')
```

That being said, utf-8 is your friend; use it. :)