# elementTree cannot parse unicode xml

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree

I have following xml:

```
<Earth>
 <country name="Česká republika" population="8900000">
    <capital>Praha1</capital>        
  </country>
</Earth>
```

But when I try to parse it fails with error:

```
 xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 2, column 20
```

my code:

```
 tree=etree.parse(input) # input -> file.xml
```

Comment: What is the encoding of the XML file?  You need to make sure you decode to Unicode.

Comment: very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147741/character-reading-from-file-in-python

try opening the with the right encoding

Comment: yep, but I'm not opening it in any way, I just use the filename as parameter of ET.parse, That's the reason why I can't manually set the encoding (or I'm not aware of ET method, that could do so)

Answer (score 1):

As arhimmel pointed out, the issue is likely an encoding issue. etree.parse allows passing file-like objects as well as paths, so you could try adding `import codecs` at the top of your code and then replacing `input` with `codecs.open("file.xml", encoding="UTF-8")`.