# How to print Unicode character in Python?

Tags: python, python-unicode

I want to make a dictionary where English words point to Russian and French translations.

How do I print out unicode characters in Python?  Also, how do you store unicode chars in a variable?

Comment: Does this help:  http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html

Comment: Have a look [here](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals). Prefixing your strings with `u` allows python to consider them as unicode string literals.

Answer (score 168):

To include Unicode characters in your Python source code, you can use [Unicode escape characters](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html#unicode-literals-in-python-source-code) in the form `\u0123` in your string. In Python 2.x, you also need to prefix the string literal with 'u'.

Here's an example running in the Python 2.x interactive console:

```
>>> print u'\u0420\u043e\u0441\u0441\u0438\u044f'
Россия
```

In Python 2, prefixing a string with 'u' declares them as Unicode-type variables, as described in the [Python Unicode documentation](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html#the-unicode-type).

In Python 3, the 'u' prefix is now optional:

```
>>> print('\u0420\u043e\u0441\u0441\u0438\u044f')
Россия
```

If running the above commands doesn't display the text correctly for you, perhaps your terminal isn't capable of displaying Unicode characters.

These examples use Unicode escapes (`\u...`), which allows you to print Unicode characters while keeping your source code as plain ASCII. This can help when working with the same source code on different systems. You can also use Unicode characters directly in your Python source code (e.g. `print u'Россия'` in Python 2), if you are confident all your systems handle Unicode files properly.

For information about reading Unicode data from a file, see this answer:

[Character reading from file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147741/character-reading-from-file-in-python)

Comment: You don't necessarily need to escape them. Define the proper file encoding via a comment on the top line and run `print u'Россия'`

Comment: Yeah, you _can_ write your code in Unicode-encoded text files, but a lot of editors and tools have trouble dealing with them. My experience with working with source code on lots of different platforms has been that it's best to keep source code in ASCII and use Unicode escapes.

Comment: @MattRyall, I agree, but a team of Russian developers may want to write comments and docstrings in Russian. For a language project it's a good option.

Comment: Though note that this only works if you print just the string.  If it's wrapped in some other object you'll see escape codes.   Try "print [u'\u0420\u043e\u0441\u0441\u0438\u044f']" for example.

Comment: What if I stored it into a string `mystr`? then how to print it?

Comment: What @cqcn1991 said; all answers just print string literals. My problem is how to print a string that is in a variable. It gives me the error "exceptions.UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2014' in position 30: ordinal not in range(128)"

Comment: @CarloWood The [top answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10569438/how-to-print-unicode-character-in-python/10569468#10569468)  tells you exactly what you want. Just `print your_unicode_characters.encode('utf-8')`

Comment: The correct spelling is print(u'россия')

Answer (score 53):

### Print a unicode character in Python:

**Print a unicode character directly from python interpreter:**

```
el@apollo:~$ python
Python 2.7.3
>>> print u'\u2713'
✓
```

Unicode character `u'\u2713'` is a checkmark.  The interpreter prints the checkmark on the screen.

**Print a unicode character from a python script:**

Put this in test.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print("here is your checkmark: " + u'\u2713');
```

Run it like this:

```
el@apollo:~$ python test.py
here is your checkmark: ✓
```

If it doesn't show a checkmark for you, then the problem could be elsewhere, like the terminal settings or something you are doing with stream redirection.

**Store unicode characters in a file:**

Save this to file: foo.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python -tt
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import codecs
import sys 
UTF8Writer = codecs.getwriter('utf8')
sys.stdout = UTF8Writer(sys.stdout)
print(u'e with obfuscation: é')
```

Run it and pipe output to file:

```
python foo.py > tmp.txt
```

Open tmp.txt and look inside, you see this:

```
el@apollo:~$ cat tmp.txt 
e with obfuscation: é
```

Thus you have saved unicode e with a obfuscation mark on it to a file.

Comment: @ofer.sheffer bizarrely I'm here looking to solve the opposite problem, the point being it may take some fiddling.

Answer (score 47):

**If you're trying to `print()` Unicode, and getting ascii codec errors**, check out [this page](http://chase-seibert.github.io/blog/2014/01/12/python-unicode-console-output.html), the TLDR of which is do `export PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8` before firing up python (this variable controls what sequence of bytes the console tries to encode your string data as).  Internally, Python3 uses UTF-8 by default (see [the Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html)) so that's not the problem; you can just put Unicode in strings, as seen in the other answers and comments.  It's when you try and get this data out to your console that the problem happens.  Python thinks your console can only handle ascii.  Some of the other answers say, "Write it to a file, first" but note they specify the encoding (UTF-8) for doing so (so, Python doesn't change anything in writing), and then use a method for reading the file that just spits out the bytes without any regard for encoding, which is why that works.

Comment: Thank you! I had a unicde problem when using the asciitree package to write results to a file. This solved it for me.

Comment: Thank you so much. Spent hours googling, glad I found this.

Comment: Add this too...
`LANG=en_US.UTF-8`
`LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8`
`LC_LANG=en_US.UTF-8`

Answer (score 21):

In Python 2, you declare unicode strings with a `u`, as in `u"猫"` and use `decode()` and `encode()` to translate to and from unicode, respectively.

It's quite a bit easier in Python 3. A very good overview can be found [here](http://pyvideo.org/video/948/pragmatic-unicode-or-how-do-i-stop-the-pain).  That presentation clarified a lot of things for me.

Comment: Thx for the video link. It is very useful.

Comment: This is also available as a non-video here: 
Pragmatic Unicode, or, How do I stop the pain? (Pycon2012)
https://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html

Answer (score 11):

Replace **'+'** with **'000'**. For example, **'U+1F600'** will become **'U0001F600'** and prepend the Unicode code with **"\"** and print.
Example:

```
>>> print("Learning : ", "\U0001F40D")
Learning :  
>>>
```

Check this maybe it will help
[python unicode emoji](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-to-print-emojis/)

Answer (score 9):

Considering that this is the first stack overflow result when google searching this topic, it bears mentioning that prefixing `u` to unicode strings is optional in Python 3. (Python 2 example was copied from the top answer)

Python 3 (both work):

```
print('\u0420\u043e\u0441\u0441\u0438\u044f')
print(u'\u0420\u043e\u0441\u0441\u0438\u044f')
```

Python 2:

```
print u'\u0420\u043e\u0441\u0441\u0438\u044f'
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I searched for: an universal way to print an unicode character inside a string both for python2 and python3.

Comment: the clamped version should work in Phyton 2 as well - clamps are an option and thus allowed.

Answer (score 8):

Python has support for `\N` as a named unicode charactrer, which can be handy if you want to make your code more readable. Here's an example:

```
assert '\N{snake}' == ''
```

Comment: The names and their support by different Python versions are listed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30302766/list-of-unicode-character-names

Answer (score 6):

Just one more thing that hasn't been added yet

In Python 2, if you want to print a variable that has unicode and use `.format()`, then do this (make the base string that is being formatted a unicode string with `u''`:

```
>>> text = "Université de Montréal"
>>> print(u"This is unicode: {}".format(text))
>>> This is unicode: Université de Montréal
```

Answer (score 4):

I use Portable winpython in Windows, it includes IPython QT console, I could achieve the following.

```
>>>print ("結婚")
結婚

>>>print ("おはよう")
おはよう

>>>str = "結婚"


>>>print (str)
結婚
```

your console interpreter should support unicode in order to show unicode characters.

Answer (score 3):

This fixes UTF-8 printing in python:

```
UTF8Writer = codecs.getwriter('utf8')
sys.stdout = UTF8Writer(sys.stdout)
```