# Unicode character with ordinal > 128 won't print after compiling with pyinstaller

Tags: python-2.7, unicode, pyinstaller

I have the following:

```
blocky = u'\u2588'
print blocky
```

When I run it in the command line everything is fine:

```
# python foo.py
█
```

Then I run `pyinstaller foo.py`. No errors. When I run the executable I get this error:

```
# ./foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testall.py", line 2, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2588' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
[8029] Failed to execute script testall
```

I've read the python unicode how-to and am still totally confused.

Edit: Just to clarify, I am especially confused about why it works *before* compiling but not *after*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't Python print Unicode symbols?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456908/why-cant-python-print-unicode-symbols)

Comment: Eh, not quite. Especially since I *have* read the how-to. See my solution below.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I found the answer. It is apparently known that python gets confused about encodings and likes defaulting to ascii. I believed that adding the initial `u` was how to explicitly declare the encoding but I guess not? Anyway, modifying it to

```
blocky = u'\u2588'
print blocky.encode("utf-8")
```

solved it.

Comment: No, that doesn't solve it, especially not in a newer version of Python, where you'll just end up trying to print a `bytes` object.

Comment: Well I just tried it and it worked. And since I'm compiling I'm not really worried about the version of python.  I am still confused about why it works *before* compiling but not *after* though....

Comment: It probably shouldn't have worked beforehand either, but you got lucky because you are writing bytes and they happen to be valid UTF-8 even though you aren't encoding them. You are almost certainly using Python 2.x and not setting a proper encoding mark in the file.

Comment: Yeah, python is 2.7 and my file is simply those 2 lines.