# List of unicode character names

Tags: python, unicode

In Python I can print a unicode character by name (e.g. `print(u'\N{snowman}')`). Is there a way I get get a list of all valid names?

Comment: That'd be the *whole Unicode standard*.

Comment: Why do you ask this question?

Comment: @MikeGraham Want to play a little game with my students.

Comment: Beware that if they have a different version of Python, the game may backfire on you: see [Martijn Pieters' answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30302840/2564301).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Every codepoint has a name, so you are effectively asking for the [*Unicode standard list of codepoint names*](https://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/NamesList.txt) (as well as the [*list of name aliases](https://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/NameAliases.txt), supported by Python 3.3 and up).

Each Python version supports a specific version of the Unicode standard; the [`unicodedata.unidata_version` attribute](https://docs.python.org/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.unidata_version) tells you which one for a given Python runtime. The above links lead to the latest published Unicode version, replace `UCD/latest` in the URLs with the value of `unicodedata.unidata_version` for your Python version.

Per codepoint, the [`unicodedata.name()` function](https://docs.python.org/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.name) can tell you the official name, and [`unicodedata.lookup()`](https://docs.python.org/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.lookup) gives you the inverse (name to codepoint).

Comment: Are functions `name` and `lookup` really inverse? Indeed, `name(lookup('space'))` returns `SPACE`. But `lookup('escape')` returns expected value and `name(lookup('escape'))` raises `ValueError: no such name`.

Comment: @Jeyekomon not all Unicode codepoints have a name; `escape` is an alias instead. `lookup()` takes names and aliases (and sequences) but `name()` only ever returns the official name. It’s mostly the control codes like escape that don’t have a name. Note that `space` is an alias, names are always uppercase. Wikipedia has a [nice overview of what doesn’t have a name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_character_property#Name).

Answer (score 5):

If you want a list of all unicode character names, consider downloading the [Unicode Character Database](http://www.unicode.org/ucd/).

It is included in the base repositories of many linux distributions (ex. "unicode-ucd" on RHEL).

The package includes [NamesList.txt](https://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/NamesList.txt), which contains the exhaustive list of unicode character names.

Caution: `NamesList.txt` need some times to be downloaded (size > 1.5 MB).

Example:

```
21FE    RIGHTWARDS OPEN-HEADED ARROW
21FF    LEFT RIGHT OPEN-HEADED ARROW
@@  2200    Mathematical Operators  22FF
@@+
@       Miscellaneous mathematical symbols
2200    FOR ALL
    = universal quantifier
2201    COMPLEMENT
    x (latin letter stretched c - 0297)
2202    PARTIAL DIFFERENTIAL
2203    THERE EXISTS
    = existential quantifier
2204    THERE DOES NOT EXIST
    : 2203 0338
2205    EMPTY SET
    = null set
    * used in linguistics to indicate a null morpheme or phonological "zero"
    x (latin capital letter o with stroke - 00D8)
    x (diameter sign - 2300)
    ~ 2205 FE00 zero with long diagonal stroke overlay form
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is a way. Going through all existing code points and calling `unicodedata.name()` on each of them. Like this:

```
names = []
for c in range(0, 0x10FFFF + 1):
    try:
        names.append(unicodedata.name(c))
    except KeyError:
        pass
# Do something with names
```

Comment: At least in Python 3, it should be `except ValueError` instead of `except KeyError`. https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.name

Answer (score 1):

For a given codepoint, you can use `unicodedata.name`. To get them all, you can work through all the billions to see which have such names.

Comment: Not billions. The standard isn't **that** big. Yet. Unicode 7.0 contains 112,804.

Comment: There aren't billions of names, but there are billions of potential codepoints to work through and check if we march through naively.

Comment: There are (and forever will be) exactly 1,114,112 potential code points. You'd have to be extremely naïve to walk the entire 32-bit space.

Answer (score 1):

Just print them all:

```
import unicodedata 

for i in range(0x110000): 
    character = chr(i) 
    name = unicodedata.name(character, "") 
    if len(name) > 0: 
        print(f"{i:6} | 0x{i:04X} | {character} | {name}")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert a unicode character by name, but don't know the name. Here is how you get an easy overview of unicode character names.

**On Windows**

1. Open "Character Map" (search for charmap.exe and run it).
2. Select any common  Microsoft font (these tend to have a wide variety of unicode characters defined).
3. Click on any character on the map to get its Unicode Character Name.

**On Mac** it's called "Character Palette" and found under System Preferences, "International -> Input" or "Language & Text -> Input Sources" by ticking the box next to "Character Palette".

Answer (score 0):

my one liner, just for my own reference ;p

```py
import unicodedata
names = [unicodedata.name(chr(c)) for c in range(0, 0x10FFFF+1) if unicodedata.name(chr(c), None)]
```