# Python: Chinese display error

Tags: python

I'm new to `python`, and I searched around didn't find any answer related to this, this is quite strange.
Essentially, this is what I'm getting (I'm using `python notebook`, with `python 2.7` )

```
In:'哈哈'
Out:'\xe5\x93\x88\xe5\x93\x88'
```

What should I do to make it display chinese properly?

Comment: How is it going in? `raw_input()`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to print Unicode character in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10569438/how-to-print-unicode-character-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can print it properly by wrapping your string with print() function.

```py
In[1]: print('哈哈')
Out[1]: '哈哈'
```

Or you can store it to a variable.

```
In[2]: input = '哈哈'
In[3]: print(input)
Out[3]: '哈哈'
```

Python interpreter uses repr() method to print out everything such as return value or variable's own value. You should use print() method explicitly to print it properly.