# sublime text 3 python doesn't print russian strings

Tags: python, sublimetext3

my test-program:

```
print ("Hello1")
print ("Привет")
print ("Hello2")
```

result:

```
Hello1
Hello2
[Finished in 0.2s]
```

In Python IDLE - everything works great.

Is there a solution for this problem?

P.S. I don't want to print in my program "\u0420\u043e\u0441\u0441\u0438". I want to print "язык" and see printed "язык".

P.P.S. Or sometimes result is even worse - it doesn't want to print English characters after russian.

```
Hello1
[Finished in 0.2s]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print Unicode character in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10569438/how-to-print-unicode-character-in-python)

Comment: Guessing, I would say that the sublime interpreter is using python 2 and your idle is python 3 maybe?

Comment: Matty - no, I think it is not duplicate. I don't want to print in my program "\u0420\u043e\u0441\u0441\u0438". I want to print "язык" and see printed "язык".

Comment: Daniel - also - no. Both - Python and IDLE use the same version of Python 3.5

Answer (score 2):

You should add the line `"encoding": "cp1251"` to your build system.
After all it loks like

```
{
"cmd": ["YOURPATH/Python/Python35-32/python.exe", "-u", "$file"],
"file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
"selector": "source.python",
"encoding": "cp1251"
}
```

Comment: No, user5856124, to my regret - it doesn't work. (I added this encoding to settings-user.)