# Conversion help in Python

Tags: python

Using Python, how can I convert this:

```
T\u00f3m l\u01b0\u1ee3c di\u1ec5n ti\u1ebfn Th\u01b0\u1ee3ng H\u1ed9i \u0110\u1ed3ng Gi\u00e1m M\u1ee5c v\u1ec1 Gia \u0110\u00ecnh\
```

To this:

```
Tóm lược diễn tiến Thượng Hội Đồng Giám Mục về Gia Đình
```

Answer (score 1):

simply write it as a unicode string:

```
s = u'T\u00f3m l\u01b0\u1ee3c di\u1ec5n ti\u1ebfn Th\u01b0\u1ee3ng H\u1ed9i \u0110\u1ed3ng Gi\u00e1m M\u1ee5c v\u1ec1 Gia \u0110\u00ecnh'
```

output:

```
'Tóm lược diễn tiến Thượng Hội Đồng Giám Mục về Gia Đình'
```

See [How to print Unicode character in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10569438/how-to-print-unicode-character-in-python) and http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html